# How do you concatenate two strings?

Tags: c++, string, string-concatenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I concatenate multiple C++ strings on one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662918/how-do-i-concatenate-multiple-c-strings-on-one-line)

How would I take:

```
string test1 = "Hello ";
string test2 = "World!";
```

and concatenate them to make one string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about

```
string test3 = test1 + test2;
```

Or maybe

```
test1.append(test2);
```

Comment: I have that ^ But it errors.. Do you know why? And I have guess defined before this.

Comment: @yankees96 Or even `guess += c;`.

Comment: @yankees96 What is the error.

Comment: And how are `guess` and `c` defined ?

Comment: Ah, it was a simple error somewhere else that we messing with me. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
string test3 = test1 + test2;
```

Or if you want to add more string literals, then :

```
string test3 = test1 + test2 + " Bye bye World!"; //ok
```

or, if you want to add it in the beginning, then:

```
string test3 = "Bye bye World!" + test1 + test2; //ok
```