# Simple string concatenation

Tags: c++

If I have a string `x='wow'` in Python, I can concatenate this string with itself using the `__add__` function, like so:

```
x='wow'  
x.__add__(x)  
'wowwow'
```

How can I do this in C++?

Comment: How about `x += x;`? It's actually quite intuitive.

Comment: (1) all FOUR answers are wrong, and (2) the closing of the question is wrong. jeez.

Comment: +1 to counter the avalanche of wrong answers and wrongful closing.

Comment: As trivial as this question is, it is clearly a real question

Comment: **please do not close the question** if you just can't understand it. thanks.

Comment: @Abyx:  by the same token, **please do not upvote this question** simply to counter the existing downvotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you concatenate two strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537820/how-do-you-concatenate-two-strings)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes:  It's not a dupe.  Two strings aren't being concatenated here.  One string is being concatenated to itself.

Comment: I tried editing the question to make it clear that it is about concatenating, not appending, as appending would imply mutating a string object as far as I can tell. Please revert or edit further if it turns out I have misunderstood :)

Comment: @John does that really change anything (note that no mutation happens here)?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it is about concatenating or appending. Both is trivial and extremely well-documented.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Mutation does happen here.  `x` is being appended to itself.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021985/what-is-the-equivalent-of-cpython-string-concatenation-in-c/

Comment: Far from the core of this question i feel like i did something awful when i posted it , i understand that it may look stupid question and some people keep voting down , i don't know what to do now to avoid earning those votes down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Semantically, the equivalent of your python code would be something like

```
std::string x = "wow";
x + x;
```

i.e. create a temporary string which is the concatenation of `x` with `x` and throw away the result. To append to `x` you would do the following:

```
std::string x = "wow";
x += x;
```

Note the double quotes `"`. Unlike python, in C++, single quotes are for single characters, and double-quotes for null terminated string literals.

See this [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) reference.

By the way, in Python you wouldn't usually call the `__add__()` method. You would use the equivalent syntax to the first C++ example:

```
x = 'wow'
x + x
```

The `__add__()` method is just the python way of providing a "plus" operator for a class.

Comment: The question is about `__add__`, which is `+` in C++, not `+=`.

Comment: @daknøk I see your point. The title says "appending to strings", but the code concatenates two strings and returns the result. I will fix my examples.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `std::string` and `operator+` or `operator+=` or a `std::stringstream` with `operator <<`.

```
std::string x("wow");
x = x + x;
//or
x += x;
```

There's also `std::string::append`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `+` operator to concatenate strings in C++:

```
std::string x = "wow";
x + x; // == "wowwow"
```

---

In Python you can also use `+` instead of `__add__` (and `+` is considered more Pythonic than `.__add__`):

```
x = 'wow'  
x + x # == 'wowwow'
```

Comment: So the equivalent to Python's `x.__add__(x)` in C++ would be `operator+(x,x)`, right? Only that I'm not sure offhand whether `+` for strings isn't a member. _Sigh._)

Comment: @sbi yes, Python’s `__add__` is equivalent to C++’ `operator+`.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string x = "wow"
x = x + x;
```

Answer (score -2):

Normally, when concatenating two distinct strings, you can simply use `operator+=` on the string you want to append to:

```
string a = "test1";
string b = "test2";

a += b;
```

Will correctly yield `a=="test1test2"`

However in this case you can't simply append a string to itself, because the act of appending changes both the source and the destination.  In other words, this is incorrect:

```
string x="wow";
x += x;
```

Instead, a simple solution is to just create a temporary (verbose for clarity):

```
string x = "wow";
string y = x;
y += x;
```

...and then swap it back:

```
x = y;
```

Comment: Why is `x += x` incorrect? The standard *requires* it to work.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes:  Where?

Comment: The effects of `operator+=` are defined as the same as the append function that takes a `char const*` and a size, described in §21.4.6.2/9. That is worded in a such a way that anything works.

Comment: The passage you refer to describes the *effects* of `append`, not the *mechanism* by which it works.  There is no explicit dispensation given in the Standard to allow `append`ing a string to itself.  Stepping through the code for `insert` under MSVC10 I see that it does work, and this is probably the case under most reasonable compilers -- but I still don't see anywhere in the Standard where it is *guaranteed* to be correct.

Comment: Those effects are given for all cases; no exceptions are listed.