# Java ToString method in C++

Tags: java, c++, tostring, type-conversion

I wonder how it is possible to have java toString method in C++ in order to convert datatypes into the string. For example, with what way it would be possible to have following code in C++.

```
public byte[] myMsg = new byte[Length];
public int intValue;
public double doubleValue;
String out1 = new String();
String out2 = new String();
String out3 = new String();

out1 += ("X; " + Long.toString((intValue& 0x1fffffff) + 0x100000000L, 16).substring(1).toUpperCase() + ";");

out2 += (" " + (Integer.toString((this.myMsg[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1)).toUpperCase());

out3 += ("; " + Double.toString(doubleValue));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, C++11 introduces something similar in [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Before that, your safest bet was to use a `std::stringstream`, fill it with `operator <<`, and retrieve the `string` with `.str()`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf well, it hasn't changed since I posted it.

Answer (score 5):

C++11 added **[`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)** functions to the standard library; check them out

Also, the Boost library has **[`lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)**.

Or you can write your own, internally using either e.g. `std::ostringstream` (from `<sstream>`) or the C library's facilities. The latter is generally more efficient (in practice).

For the general concatenation + formatting expressions that you show, you should instead consider a general formatter that can do that in linear time.

A simple (not particularly efficient or feature-rich) such formatter is shown in full in [another question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021985/what-is-the-equivalent-of-cpython-string-concatenation-in-c).

Answer (score 4):

Templates

Code:

```
template <typename T>
std::string toString(const T &val_p)
{
    std::stringstream x;
    x << val_p;
    return x.str();  
}
```

This function will convert ANY type of object to a string, provided that the appropriate ostream insertion operator is defined. To convert custom objects, you merely write a function:

Code:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream_p, const my_class &val_p)
{
    // ...
    return stream_p;
}
```

Comment: **A refinement**: To show that the intent is to **output** a string, replace `std::stringstream` with `std::ostringstream` in the above `template`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292107/whats-the-difference-between-istringstream-ostringstream-and-stringstream-w) for a relevant discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, C++11 has made `to_string` part of its language (as a free function).

However it does not replace using `ostringstream`, and if you are building a string of a lot of objects, it is better to continue using `ostringstream` rather than convert each item to a string and concatenate them.

The reason is that when you use `ostringstream`, it will create a buffer into which to write the output. When you call `to_string` then concatenate, it is likely `to_string` will create its own `ostringstream` object with its own buffer.

If users are going to be using operator+ to concatenate strings this will be very inefficient. If they create a big ostringstream to start with you may as well stream the objects in direct rather than call to_string on them first.

I actually foresee this being primarily used for logging and exception throwing. In the latter case efficiency probably doesn't matter.

(Code I have seen using boost's datetime library and streaming commonly suffers from the "create a new facet and locale for every date I print/parse" inefficiency. I have fixed that inefficiency in 2 companies where I have worked).