# c++: function that concats all its arguments as a string

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

I need to write a function `concat` like:

```
std::string concat(...);
```

that accepts any number of arguments
of varying types(char, char*, int, std::string, ...)
and returns their concatenation. for example:

```
concat(88,'a',"home",9) == std::string("88ahome9")
```

Comment: This is a combination of two questions. 1) How to allow a varying number of arguments in a function call. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657883/variable-number-of-arguments-in-c). 2) How to concatenate various string types. That question is very basic, there are dozens of examples online if you search.

Comment: You might want to read about [template prameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) and [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662918/how-do-i-concatenate-multiple-c-strings-on-one-line/23910249#23910249, my answer there provides what you ask for.

Answer (score 6):

You may use the following:

```
template<typename ... Ts>
std::string concat(Ts&&...args)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    const int dummy[] = {0, (ss << std::forward<Ts>(args), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(dummy);  // avoid warning for unused variable
    return ss.str();
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/4TsWUw)

or in C++17, with Folding expression

```
template<typename ... Ts>
std::string concat(Ts&&...args)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    (ss << ... << std::forward<Ts>(args));
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: Interesting way to do the expansion. It'd be nice if any arbitrary expression could be expanded into a sequence of comma operators: `(ss << std::forward<Ts>(args)) ...;`. There's probably a good reason why this isn't possible.

Comment: great but I'm looking for a solution in c++03

Comment: So the requirement should be stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ostringstream convert function in the sstream library.

You would start with a line such as

ostringstream convert;

Then with the << operator convert the variable you wish(or >> to convert from string), like:

int var = 98;

convert << var;

Then store this in a string:

string result;

result = convert.str();

That string will now contain the contents of your int!

Ofc you can use if statements to differentiate between input as chars, ints, etc. And combine all the strings at the end to concate them.

Btw sorry for spelling and format, on phone xD