# No whitespace between concatenated strings

Tags: c++, string

I've been trying to write this code on concatenated strings:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    string line, total;
    //Read strings from the input//
    cout<<"Enter a String"<< endl;
    while(getline(cin,line)){
        cout<< "Enter another String"<< endl;
        if(!line.empty())
        total+=line;
        cout<<" Concatenated string is\t"<<total<< endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, my output has no space existing between the two appended strings. I also need a way to terminate the added strings.

Comment: string's operator+= does not implicitly add space. So you have to do it manually: `total += " " + line;`.

Comment: There are plenty of answers like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662918/how-do-i-concatenate-multiple-c-strings-on-one-line. See comment above for a simpler solution

Comment: What do you mean by 'terminating' the added strings?

Comment: I meant if you run the code, each instance I prompt the user to enter a string, both the enter a string prompt and the concatenated string output appear on the screen together. I was hoping that the output displays enter a string first and then the next line would display enter another string etc thus then the following line would display the concatenated string if I only choose to enter only two strings. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+=` doesn’t automatically adds space between two strings. You need to manually add it.

Something like this:

```
total += " " + line;
```

Also, this article provides explanation with example about += operator.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/

Answer (score 1):

Operator `+=` does not add spaces for you.
You would need to add space explicitly, something like `total += " " + line;`

Answer (score 0):

> *"However, my output has no space existing between the two appended strings."*

To put spaces between your concatenated strings, just add them

```
 total += ' ' + line;
       // ^^^
```

> *"I also needed a way to terminate the added strings."*

To end the loop you could for instance have an `else` branch on the `if(!line.empty())` test with a `break;` statement.
When an empty string was input, the loop and the program ends.

Comment: I had abrupt exiting of the windows C++ console when I included the break statement. so I tried the if else statement  without  the break statement, it works without the break.  However when I enter an empty string upon a prompt. The output displays the enter the string prompt,  with the appended string output. I was under the impression that upon entering the empty string only the appended string would be printed not with the prompt enter a string.

Comment: @dirty_sanchez _"I had abrupt exiting of the windows C++ console when I included the break statement"_ You can run your program in debug mode and set a breakpoint at the last brace `}` in `main()`. That will keep the console open. Alternatively you can put a `getch();` statement after your loop.