# How to put a space between two strings c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string x  ;
    string y ;
    string sum;
    string z = " " ;
    
  cout << "Write your name:" ;
  cin >> x ;
cout  << "Write your second name:" ;
cin >>  y ;
  sum = (x+z+y) ;
  cout << "your name is:" << sum ;
  
  return 0 ;
}
```

Is there another way to add a space between this two names other than string z = " "
to be like that your name is first name( space)second name

Comment: `sum = x + " " + y;`

Comment: You can add space to printing `cout << "your number is: " << x << ' ' << y;`

Comment: See [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28259815/12002570).

Comment: Not what you're asking, but should it say "Your **name** is: "?