# Why cant I add char* to char* by return in cpp?

Tags: c++

I have this code sample in which I try to concatenate strings:

```
const char* NameErrorException::what() const throw()
{
    return "NameError : name '" + _name + "' is not defined";
}
```

Why cant I create a `char*` by use of `+` between strings?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662918/how-do-i-concatenate-multiple-c-strings-on-one-line

Comment: You can't use + to concatenate them. Either use `strcat` or the more safe way `snprintf`. Actually, just use `std::string`.

Comment: because C++ is not Java (this is by far, the best answer here)

Comment: @DavidHaim At least you said so yourself.

Comment: @GillBates I'm kidding, but seriously, usually when new developers ask about why something is not possible in C++, they usually mean "In Java/C#/Python it is possible, how come it's impossible in C++?". this question is probably one of these

Comment: @DavidHaim mhm, to be honest, since everyone places C++ next to those languages in terms of "levelness" (high-level, low-level etc). `const char*` should be banned.

Comment: @GillBates perhapse, if we were to redesign C++ from scratch in modern point of view.

Comment: @DavidHaim we'd use `std::string` literals `"yada yada"s`, which behave as expected :)

Comment: @GillBates Not necessarily banned, just because it's there you don't have to use it. That's like saying to get rid of pointers in favour of smart pointers, or manual memory management because it's hard. You'd end up with Java and then we'd all be in trouble.

Comment: @Colin__s Banned in classes, banned to teach new programmers to return a bare `const char*`.

Comment: @GillBates Yes. Institutions should start teaching modern C++, that I agree with.

Comment: Or they could teach C and assembler before teaching C++, so that programmers actually have a clue about what they are doing. Now if there existed a language with was sane, compiled and fast at the same time, we wouldn't need C or C++ at all... For now, we'll just have to settle for compiled and fast.

Comment: @GillBates: Please note that this is an overload of `std::exception::what` which is defined to return a char*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of this is simple:  You can't add `char *` variables with + because C++ is not Java (or Python, or C#).

You may have learnt that "`const char*` represents a string in C++".  This is true as far as it goes, but if you use `const char*` like that, you have all the responsibility of allocating and freeing memory at the right time.

In general, you are *much* better off using `std::string` to represent a string.  It is safe to return a `std::string` from your function - it is not safe to return a `const char*` (who is responsible for freeing the memory)?

However, there is one exception to that rule:  When you are overriding `std::exception::what()` - which is defined to return a `const char*`.  The fix is that you need an additional (`std::string`) member of `NameErrorException` which you construct at the same time as you construct `_name`, and which you set to the full error message, and then `what` just returns `_what_error.c_str()`.  So the full class would look something like:

```
class NameErrorException : public std::runtime_error
{
    std::string _name;
    std::string _what_error;
    std::string build_error(const std::string &name)
    {
        // Use std::string literals.
        return "NameError : name '"s + name + "' is not defined"s;
    }
public:
    NameErrorException(const std::string& name) 
    : _name(name)
    , _what_error(build_error(name))
    {}

    const char* what() const throw() override
    {
        return _what_error.c_str();
    }
}
```

If you don't have `std::string` literals, you will have to make `build_error` be:

```
        return std::string("NameError : name '") + name + "' is not defined"s;
```

Comment: I think there is an overload for `operator+` with pointers and strings in any order, so one normal string is enough when concatenating multiple strings. It's normally the first operand, but second is good too.

Answer (score 6):

"Sesame Street 3" plus 4 houses ahead means "Sesame Street 7".

but what does "Sesame Street 3" plus "Sesame Street 4" means?
 it means nothing.
 you can add a house-offset to a street address, but what does it even mean to add two street addresses together? it makes no sense. "Sesame Street 3" plus "Sesame Street 4" IS NOT "Sesame Street 7".

`const char*` is a location of a character on the RAM. adding yet another location will not create new string. it is meaningless. just like adding two street addresses will not create a new street address (or a new street, for that example).

`const char*` is (usually) C-String. it knows nothing about string concatenation, splitting, removing or replacing. it's just the location of the first character on the RAM. this is why usually, in C++ we do use `std::string`. `std::string` is an object with behaviour. it DOES know about actions like concatenation, splitting, removing or replacing.

Answer (score 2):

A `char *` is a pointer to a char. The `+` operator can be used to add an offset to a pointer, not concatenate c strings.

Comment: You can add an integer and a pointer, but not two pointers. A nitpick, but terse answers require precise wording.

Comment: "For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a pointer to a complete object type and the other shall have integer type." Which is why this won't compile.

Comment: @Colin__s - see David Haim's "Sesame Street" answer for a good explanation

Answer (score -1):

You get the error because `operator+` is not used for concatenation of c-strings. `operator+` is only defined for adding index values to pointers.

You can fix this by creating an `std::string` object inside the `NameErrorException` object and initializing it when the exception is created (i.e. in the constructor):

```
class NameErrorException : public std::runtime_error {
private:
    std::string _errorString;  // Used to store the error message.

public:
    // Constructor.
    NameErrorException(const char * const name) {
        _errorString.append("NameError : name '");
        _errorString.append(name);
        _errorString.append("' is not defined");
    }

    virtual const char * what() {
        return _errorString.c_str();
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you can create a second `const char *` buffer that is the correct size, and use [`std::snprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) or  [`std::strncat()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncat) to create the string. (Remember to clean up the new buffer inside your destructor!)

Comment: `operator +` is defined for all pointer types.  otherwise `variable + number` or `variable[index]` would not compile.

Comment: But it's not defined for addition of two pointer types.