# using a variable in regex cpp

Tags: c++, regex

I have a string:

```
string str1= "hello"; 
string str2="hel";
```

And I am doing this to see if str1 has str2 in it:

```
regex e = str2+"*"
 bool x=regex_match(str1,e); 
cout<<x;
```

I am getting this : error: conversion from 'std::__cxx11::basic_string' to non-scalar type 'std::__cxx11::regex {aka std::__cxx11::basic_regex}' requested regex e = str2+"";

How to use the variable in my regex. Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong? TIA.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662918/how-do-i-concatenate-multiple-c-strings-on-one-line

Comment: what types are `str1`, `str2`, `hello` and `hel`? How are they defined? Can you provide the complete code that produces the problem?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that question is for concatenation of string!

Comment: Also note that the regex `hel*` _will_ match `hello`, but not for the reason you probably think.

Comment: @hydra123 Right. But that is what you need. Concatenate the *string patterns* and then build the `regex` object.

Comment: In your real code does `hello` have quotes round it or is it another variable?

Comment: @Galik hello has quotes around it.

Comment: It is just hard to guess what the error is when the code you posted is not the same code that produces your error.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, great . Thanks that worked .

Comment: To see if str1 has str2 you should not add * at the end.

Comment: While this is probably a learning exercise, it's worth pointing out that using a regular expression for this particular search is overkill. `str1.find(str2)` will tell you whether `str2` occurs anywhere in `str1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at reference about constructor of `regex`

```
template <class ST, class SA>
explicit basic_regex ( const basic_string<charT,ST,SA>& str, flag_type flags = 
 ECMAScript );
```

constructor is explicit so you should write

```
    regex e(str2+"*");
```

not

```
    regex e = str2+"*";
```