# How to return time as DD:HH:MM:SS?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, time, return

I would like to develop [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) application which provides *day, hour, minute and second* inputs from a user with setters. I am getting values from the user with setters correctly.

But I can not return value as `DD:HH:MM:SS`. I coded a method called `getDate` and expect to get all values in that method but it only returns the second value of `Date2` object.

Here is what I tried.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Date
{
public:
    int getDate(void)
    {
        return day, std::string(":"), hour, std::string(":"), minute, std::string(":"), second;
    }
    int getDay(void) {
        return day;
    }
    int getHour(void) {
        return hour;
    }
    int getMinute(void) {
        return minute;
    }
    int getSecond(void) {
        return second;
    }
    void setDay(int a) {
        day= a;
    }
    void setHour(int b) {
        hour = b;
    }
    void setMinute(int c) {
        minute = c;
    }
    void setSecond(int d) {
        second = d;
    }

private:    
    int day;
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;
};

// Main function for the program
int main()
{
    Date Date1;                
    Date Date2;                                
    int day= 0;     
    int hour= 0;
    int minute = 0;
    int second= 0;
    // Date1 specification
    Date1.setDay(23);
    Date1.setHour(14);
    Date1.setMinute(43);
    Date1.setSecond(21);

    // Tarih2  specification
    Date2.setDay(12);
    Date2.setHour(43);
    Date2.setMinute(25);
    Date2.setSecond(49);
    day = Date1.getDay();
    cout << "Day of Date1 : " << day << endl;
    hour = Date1.getHour();
    cout << "Hour of Date1 : " << hour << endl;
    minute = Date1.getMinute();
    cout << "Minute of Date1 : " << minute << endl;
    second = Date1.getSecond();
    cout << "Second of Date1 : " << second << endl;

    cout << "Date1 : " << Date1.getDate()<< endl;

    cout << "Date2 : " << Date2.getDate()<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `return day, std::string(":"), hour, std::string(":"), minute, std::string(":"), second;` to give you?  Why does the function have the return type `int`?

Comment: You want a `string`, yet you are returning `int`. That makes *no* sense.

Answer (score 2):

Your `int getDate(void)` function is wrong. To format the member variables to the for `DD:HH:MM:SS`, you could

1. either rewrite the `getDate` function in such a way that it **returns
   a `std::string`** *[after concatenating the class
   members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662918/how-do-i-concatenate-multiple-c-strings-on-one-line)*
   together to `DD:HH:MM:SS` format.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <sstream>  // std::stringstream

   class Date
   {
   private:
       // members
   public:
       std::string getDate() /* const noexcept */
       {
           std::stringstream sstr; // DD:HH:MM:SS
           sstr << day << ":" << hour << ":" << minute << ":" << second << '\n';
           return sstr.str();
       }
       // other codes
   };

   int main()
   {
       Date obj{};
       std::cout << obj.getDate(); // should print as DD:HH:MM:SS
   }
   ```
2. Or **provide an output stream
   *[`operator<<`overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=vs-2019)***
   which is the usual [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) approach.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <sstream>   // std::stringstream

   class Date
   {
   private:
       // members
   public:
       friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Date& obj) /* noexcept */;
       // other member functions
   };
   // outside the class defenition
   std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Date& obj) /* noexcept */
   {
       std::stringstream sstr; // DD:HH:MM:SS
       sstr << obj.day << ":" << obj.hour << ":" << obj.minute << ":" << obj.second << '\n';
       return out << sstr.str();
   }

   int main()
   {
       Date obj{};
       std::cout << obj; // will console out in DD:HH:MM:SS format
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
return day, std::string(":"), hour, std::string(":"), minute, std::string(":"), second;
```

What's this?
Use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) or a variant of it.

```
char buff[100] = {0};
sprintf_s(buff, 100, "%02u:%02u", hours, minutes);
```

Comment: I don't know how can I use this in my code.Can you make it on my code please?

Comment: Why use `sprintf` in C++? Why not `std::string`?

Comment: Because sprintf is also C++.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis True. It *is*. But it's part of the clunky null-terminated-string stuff we inherited from C and that noone should be using unless forced to. C++ can do better than that legacy thing.

Comment: sprintf (and the entire printf family) has no real C++ replacement. Even if 99% of the language is modern, there is no need to use something inferior just because it's more modern than the older one. And in any case my answer was referring to the way he should avoid the return line he has.

Comment: There may be times you will wish to use C functions such as sprintf, like when you have requirements for them, or your efforts are to provide 'end-of-life' support form some older code (just to last a little longer). I think these are about the only reasons to think about them.   But the C style code is not for new efforts.  Not for learning c++.  Kudo's to you, Alex Webster, for your class date.  Your effort is clearly not hospice for other peoples code..

Comment: @jes: Using `std::string` doesn't solve the formatting requirements, unless you are willing to write lengthy workarounds, that are hard to write and hard to read. There is no value in being dogmatic about rejecting C library code just because it is C library code. C++ currently doesn't have anything equally succinct to offer (until C++20 introduces [std::chrono::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/format)).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put everything into a string ? 
Create one string, for example: `string fullDate`, and add everything into it and then return it

Comment: can you give me an example on my code please?

Comment: I am sorry my internet is quite buggy. What i meant is:
string fullDate;
fullDate = to_string(day) + ":" + to_string(hour) + ":" + to_string(minute) + ":" + to_string(second);

Comment: And when you have that string, just use return fullDate to return it. Also, your function must be "string getDate", not int.

Comment: it doesn't recognize to_string(int)

Comment: What compiler are you using ?

Comment: to_string is in header < string >

Comment: I'm using visual studio

Comment: C++ also has stringstream (in header  < sstream > ), which you can use ( just like cout ) to build the string.  So, if you can cout what you want, try a stringstream.   Access to the string 'inside-of-stringstream' is simple.  See the documentation.

Comment: @AlexWebster for `std::to_string` you need at least C++11 support from your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use 'tm' structure?
[struct tm - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/)

Here go some code that I always have "on sleeve".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

time_t GetDateTime_TT(int &ms)
{
  chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> TpNow = chrono::system_clock::now();
  chrono::system_clock::duration Durat = TpNow.time_since_epoch();
  long long Millis = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(Durat).count();
  time_t Tt = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(TpNow);
  ms = Millis % 1000;
  return Tt;
}

tm *GetDateTime_TM(int &ms)
{
  time_t Tt = GetDateTime_TT(ms);
  tm *Tm = localtime(&Tt);
  return Tm;
}

string DateTimeToString(tm *tm, const string &format)
{
  char buf[90];
  strftime(buf, 90, format.c_str(), tm);
  return string(buf);
}

tm StringToDateTime_TM(const string &value, const string &format)
{
  tm tm;
  tm.tm_year = 0;
  tm.tm_mon = 0;
  tm.tm_mday = 0;
  tm.tm_hour = 0;
  tm.tm_min = 0;
  tm.tm_sec = 0;
  tm.tm_yday = 0;
  tm.tm_wday = 0;
  tm.tm_isdst = 0;
  istringstream iss(value);
  iss >> get_time(&tm, format.c_str());
  return tm;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int ms;
  tm *Now = GetDateTime_TM(ms);
  string DT = DateTimeToString(Now, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
  cout << "Now: " << DT.c_str() << "\n";
  tm *End = &StringToDateTime_TM("2019-12-31 23:59:59", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but this is a homework and I'm not able to use this