# best way to return an std::string that local to a function

Tags: c++, return-value

In C++ what is the best way to return a function local std::string variable from the function?

```
std::string MyFunc()
{
    std::string mystring("test");
    return mystring;

}

std::string ret = MyFunc(); // ret has no value because mystring has already gone out of scope...???
```

Comment: You are returning by-value, not by reference. As such it doesn't matter that 'mystring' is gone.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

No. That is not true. Even if `mystring` has gone out of scope and is destroyed, `ret` has a copy of mystring as the function `MyFunc` returns by value.

Comment: Technically speaking, it is not a copy.

Comment: Won't the internal (heap) data be deleted too when the original string object goes out of scope and gets destructed? If that's the case, does returning make a deep copy?

Answer (score 25):

There will be a problem if your code is like:

```
std::string& MyFunc()
{
    std::string mystring("test");
    return mystring;
}
```

So, the way you've written it is OK. Just one advice - if you can construct the string like this, I mean - you can do it in one row, it's sometimes better to do it like this:

```
std::string MyFunc()
{
    return "test";
}
```

Or if it's more "complicated", for example:

```
std::string MyFunct( const std::string& s1,
                     const std::string& s2,
                     const char* szOtherString )
{
    return std::string( "test1" ) + s1 + std::string( szOtherString ) + s2;
}
```

This will give a **hint** to your compiler to do more optimization, so it could do one less copy of your string ([RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization)).

Comment: Why the explicit cast, anyway? Doesn’t that cloud the issue? Just doing `return "foo";` works like a charm.

Answer (score 19):

None of the previous answers contained the *key notion* here. That notion is *move semantics*. The `std::string` class has the `move` constructor, which means it has *move semantics*. *Move semantics* imply that the object is not copied to a different location on function return, thus, providing faster function execution time.

Try to step debug into a function that returns `std::string` and examine the innards of that object that is about to be return. You shall see a member field pointer address `xxx`. And then, examine the `std::string` variable that received the function's return value. You shall see the same pointer address `xxx` in that object.

This means, **no copying** has occurred, ladies and gentlemen. This is the *move semantics*, God bless America!

Comment: Good answer...but really @daparic...what on earth does America have to do with this post, let alone StackOverflow [on a forum used by software developers globally]?

Comment: God bless you !

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned, the std::string is copied. So even the original local variable has gone out of scope, the caller gets a copy of the std::string.

I think reading on [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) can totally clear your confusion. In this case, it's accurately referred to as NRVO (Named RVO) but the spirit is the same.

*Bonus reading*: The problem with using RVO is that it's not the most flexible thing in the world. One of the big buzzes of C++0x is [rvalue references](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/rvalue.html) which intends to solve that problem.

Comment: There are two flavors of RVO: URVO (Unnamed RVO) relates to temporaries and NRVO (Named RVO) relates to local variables. URVO is usually simpler (for the compiler). NRVO is more difficult, because with named variables you could have various `return` statement, each returning a different variable. At this point the optimizer has to pick **1** variable as the one being optimized, and all the other paths will yield a copy.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried it?
The string is copied when it's returned.
Well that's the official line, actually the copy is probably optimised away, but either way it's safe to use.

Comment: Actually, in the case of a class like std::string with a non-trivial copy constructor, it can't be optimised away, but it will be in cases where the class does have a trivial copy constructor.

Comment: "in the case of a class...with a non-trivial constructor, it can't be optimised away" -- Oh, but it can, and usually is.  Try this: std::string * sp; std::string func()
{
    std::string s("bla");
    sp = &s;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = func();
    if(sp == &s)
        std::cout << "YAY";
    else
        std::cout << "BOO";
} -- On my compiler (VS) It prints YAY.

Comment: what PigBen wrote of course results in undefined behavior, but even under defined circumstances the compiler has the right elide the copy sometimes. Google for RVO and NRVO.

Answer (score 3):

Well, ret will have a value of mystring after MyFunc(). In case of returning the result by value a temporary object is constructed by copying the local one.

As for me, there are some interesting details about the topic in these sections of [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.9).

Comment: What are some of those interesting details? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the use case. If an instance should keep responsibility for a string, strings should be returned by a const reference. The problem is, what to do, if there isn't any object to return. With pointers, the invalid object could be signaled using 0. Such a "null-object" could be also used with references (e.g., NullString in the code snippet).

Of course, a better way to signal an invalid return value is throwing exceptions.

Another use case is if the responsibility for the string is transferred to the caller. In this case *auto_ptr* should be used. The code below shows all this use cases.

```
#include <string>
#include <memory> //auto_ptr
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::auto_ptr;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

static const string NullString("NullString\0");


///// Use-Case: GETTER //////////////////
//assume, string should be found in a list
//  and returned by const reference

//Variant 1: Pseudo null object
const string & getString( bool exists ) {
  //string found in list
  if( exists ) {
    static const string str("String from list");
    return str;
  }
  //string is NOT found in list
  return NullString;
}

//Variant 2: exception
const string & getStringEx( bool available ) {
  //string found in list
  if( available ) {
    static const string str("String from list");
    return str;
  }

  throw 0; //no valid value to return
}

///// Use-Case: CREATER /////////////////
auto_ptr<string> createString( bool ok )
{
  if( ok ){
    return auto_ptr<string>(new string("A piece of big text"));
  }else{
    return auto_ptr<string>();
  }
}

int main(){
  bool ok=true, fail=false;
  string str;
  str = getString( ok );
  cout << str << ", IsNull:"<<( str == NullString )<<endl;
  str = getString( fail );
  cout << str << ", IsNull:"<<( str == NullString )<<endl;

  try{
    str = getStringEx( ok );
    cout << str <<endl;
    str = getStringEx( fail );
    cout << str <<endl; //line won't be reached because of ex.
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    cout << "EX: no valid value to return available\n";
  }

  auto_ptr<string> ptext = createString( ok );
  if ( ptext.get() ){
    cout << *ptext << endl;
  } else {
      cout << " Error, no text available" << endl;
  }

  ptext = createString( fail );
  if ( ptext.get() ){
    cout << *ptext << endl;
  } else {
      cout << " Error, no text available"<<endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```