# C++: how to add int to current string in C++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ concatenate string and int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191757/c-concatenate-string-and-int)

Hi,

In C# I can write like this:

```
int i = 0;
string text = "out.jpg";
while(true)
{
     i++;
     Object.write(i+text, stream);
}
```

But this is not true for C++. the problem is at: i + default.

How could I fix this in C++?

Thanks in advance. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: What kind of behavior were you expecting?

Comment: Btw, don't use `default` as a variable name.

Comment: @wilhelmtell The suggestions weren’t very good.

Comment: Hi all, I just tried this and it works perfectly: int i = 0;char text[] = "ok";sprintf(text, "hello %d ok.jpg", i); Object.write(text, stream); Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `stringstream`...

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << i << text;
Object.write(ss.str(), stream);
```

Comment: +1. First I thought about `sprintf()`, but this is not really a C++ solution, rather a C one and it requires some usage of a `char` array. Using `stringstream` is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

`default` is a keyword in C++. You can't have `string default` in C++. And I don't see what you are trying to achieve. Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

take a look at stringstreams or boost.format http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/format/doc/format.html

```
boost::format("%1%%2%") % i % default_;
```

Answer (score 0):

`default` is a reserved keyword.  Change the variable name to `defaultStr` or similar, and everything should work fine.