# String concatenation in C++ problem

Tags: c++

everybody I have problem with string concatenation in C++, here is my code

```
map<double, string> fracs;
for(int d=1; d<=N; d++)
    for(int n=0; n<=d; n++)            
        if(gcd(n, d)==1){
            string s = n+"/"+d;// this does not work in C++ but works in Java
            fracs.insert(make_pair((double)(n/d), s));
            }
```

How can I fix my code?

Comment: Commencing psychic reading, please wait... ERROR: Could not read OP's mind. Post the goddamn error.

Comment: It is already discussed in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191757/c-concatenate-string-and-int

Comment: i would like to get map<double, string> where double is the value of fraction (n/d) and string is ("n/d"), then I want to print it to file

Comment: @phresnel and @the_drow The source of the error is as obvious as it can be. The OP even commented the line. Maybe the problem is on your end?

Comment: @Paul: Right, mea culpa.

Comment: @torayeff: go ahead, vote good answers up, and accept an answer if you find it suitable; otherwise, people in future are not motivated to help you anymore

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you have to convert an `int` to a `string` before you can concatenate it with another `string` using the + operator.

See [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c).

Comment: You don't have to when you pass non-string types to output streams (they will do the conversion for you).

Comment: But concatenation. And the canonical C++ way of concatenating non-string values is with streams.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this.

```
stringstream os;
os << n << "/" << d;
string s =os.str();
```

Comment: Is this save against buffer overflow attacks ?

Answer (score 2):

Use streams, in your case, a stringstream:

```
#include <sstream>
...
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << n << '/' << d;
```

Later, when done with your work, you can store it as an ordinary string:

```
const std::string s = ss.str();
```

---

Important (side-) note: **Never** do

```
const char *s = ss.str().c_str();
```

`stringstream::str()` produces a *temporary* `std::string`, and according to the standard, temporaries live until the end of the expression. Then, `std::string::c_str()` gives you a pointer to a null-terminated string, but according to The Holy Law, that C-style-string  becomes invalid once the `std::string` (from which you receved it) changes.

> It might work this time, and next time, and even on QA, but explodes right in the face of your most valuable customer.

The `std::string` must survive until the battle is over:

```
const std::string s = ss.str(); // must exist as long as sz is being used
const char *sz = s.c_str();
```

Answer (score 0):

`n` and `d` are integers. Here is how you can convert integer to string:

```
std::string s;
std::stringstream out;
out << n << "/" << d;
s = out.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in Java, in C++ there is no `operator+` that explicitly converts a number to a string. What is usually done in C++ in cases like this is...

```
#include <sstream>

stringstream ss;
ss << n << '/' << d; // Just like you'd do with cout
string s = ss.str(); // Convert the stringstream to a string
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/).

```
stringstream s;
s << n << "/" << d;
fracs.insert(make_pair((double)n/d, s.str()));
```

Answer (score 0):

No one has suggested it yet but you can also take a look at [`boost::lexical_cast<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm).

While this method is sometimes criticized because of performance issues, it might be ok in your situation, and it surely makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I think sprintf(), which is a function used to send formatted data to strings, would be a much clearer way to do it. Just the way you would use printf, but with the c-style string type char* as a first(additional) argument:

```
char* temp;
sprint(temp, "%d/%d", n, d);
std::string g(temp);
```

You could check it out at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/