# Concatenating two QStrings with an integer

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I want to do something like this in C++ using Qt:

```
int i = 5;
QString directory = ":/karim/pic" + i + ".jpg";
```

where `+` means I want to concatenate the strings and the integer (that is, `directory` should be `:/karim/pic5.jpg`). How can I do this?

Comment: C++ concatenate string and int http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191757/c-concatenate-string-and-int
There is an answer with 8 ways to do it in there.

Comment: The tags indicate he wants an answer for `qt`, the answers in the "duplicate" don't provide that.

Comment: Ok, I missed it being a Qt question, voted for reopen. The solution is: `QString dir = ":/karim/pic" + QString::number(i) + ".jpg";`

Comment: This is not the optimal solution, but since all the solutions tell how to do it with `std::string`, if you ever need a `QString` and you have an `std::string`, use [this function](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#fromStdString)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Qt's idiom for things like this is the [`arg()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg)function of QString.

```
QString directory = QString(":/karim/pic%1.jpg").arg(i);
```

Comment: Slightly better is `QStringLiteral(":/karim/pic%1.jpg").arg(i);`, which is generated at compile time. https://woboq.com/blog/qstringliteral.html

Answer (score 12):

(EDIT: this is an answer to the question before the edit that mentioned QString. For QString, see [the newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011447/concatenating-two-qstring-with-an-integer/7014829#7014829))

This can be done as a very similar one-liner using [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11):

```
int i = 5;
std::string directory = ":/karim/pic" + std::to_string(i) + ".jpg";
```

Test: https://ideone.com/jIAxE

With older compilers, it can be substituted with [Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_C++_Libraries):

```
int i = 5;
std::string directory = ":/karim/pic" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i) + ".jpg";
```

Test: https://ideone.com/LFtt7

But the classic way to do it is with a string stream object.

```
int i = 5;
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << ":/karim/pic" << i << ".jpg";
std::string directory = oss.str();
```

Test: https://ideone.com/6QVPv

Comment: Interesting.  I never knew, all this time that there was an overload for `operator+(const char *, const std::string &)`, and so I would always have to wrap my literals in a string constructor.

Comment: @Karim M. El Tel: Ohh, since it's a QString (after edit), go with hexa's comment. Hopefully it will get reopened so it can be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int i = 5;

std::stringstream s;
s << ":/karim/pic" << i << ".jpg";

std::string directory = s.str();
```

Comment: I think it's `s.str()`, not `s.string()`

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at stringstream:

http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/

```
ostringstream oss(ostringstream::out);

oss << ":/karim/pic";
oss << i
oss << ".jpg";

cout << oss.str();
```

Comment: You need to include <sstream>.