# Concatenate stl string+int+int+int in QString

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concatenating two QStrings with an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011447/concatenating-two-qstrings-with-an-integer)

i'm looking forward to create a a string from 3 ints and one c++ stl string in QT, how can i do this? anyone know?, can't find something thats explain this procces?

this is my code were i create the elements in a lsit,  but i want to print all elements and theyr properties not only name:

```
void Window::listMovies(){
ui->listMovies->clear();
vector <Movie> all = ctrl->getAllMovies();
for(int i=0; i <(int) all.size();i++){
    QListWidgetItem*item = new QListWidgetItem(
                QString::fromStdString(all[i].getName()),ui->listMovies);
    item->setData(Qt::UserRole,QVariant::fromValue(all[i].getID()));
```

Movie objects have 1 string and 3 ints varaibles.

Comment: Duplicate: [Concatenating two QStrings with an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7011447/594137)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
QString str = QString::fromStdString( stl_string ) + " " +
              QString::number( num1 ) + " " +
              QString::number( num2 ) + " " +
              QString::number( num1 );
```

There are a few different ways doing this.

Comment: thanks, easy, really pythonic way :p

Answer (score 4):

Use the `arg()` functionality of `QString`. Here is a real world example:

```
QString title("<b>Select Region of Interest:</b> %1.%2 - %3.%4 (%5x%6)");
title = title.arg(roi.x()).arg(roi.y()).arg(roi.right()).arg(roi.bottom())
.arg(roi.width()).arg(roi.height());
```

I assume you get the idea. [Find it here in the Qt 4.8 documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#arg).