# saving files in c++ at different full paths

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am writing a program in C++ which I need to save some .txt files to different locations as per the counter variable in program what should be the code? Please help

I know how to save file using full path

```
ofstream f;
f.open("c:\\user\\Desktop\\**data1**\\example.txt");
f.close();
```

I want "c:\user\Desktop\data**[CTR]**\filedata.txt"

But here the data1,data2,data3 .... and so on have to be accessed by me and create a textfile in each so what is the code?
Counter variable "ctr" is already evaluated in my program.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191757/c-concatenate-string-and-int

Answer (score 2):

You could `snprintf` to create a custom string. An example is this:

```
char filepath[100];
snprintf(filepath, 100, "c:\\user\\Desktop\\data%d\\example.txt", datanum);
```

Then whatever you want to do with it:

```
ofstream f;
f.open(filepath);
f.close();
```

**Note:** `snprintf` limits the maximum number of characters that can be written on your buffer (`filepath`). This is very useful for when the arguments of `*printf` are strings (that is, using `%s`) to avoid buffer overflow. In the case of this example, where the argument is a number (`%d`), it is already known that it cannot have more than 10 characters and so the resulting string's length already has an upper bound and just making the `filepath` buffer big enough is sufficient. That is, in this special case, `sprintf` could be used instead of `snprintf`.

Comment: well thanks for the answer u solved my problem 99% but it stops working for even just 8 loops .R u getting me...

Comment: @KB807 this code should work.  If it stops after 8, that's your code, not this

Comment: @KB2807, don't be shy to accept the answer if it solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the standard string streams, such as:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

void f ( int data1 )
{
     ostringstream path;
     path << "c:\\user\\Desktop\\" << data1 << "\\example.txt";
     ofstream file(path.str().c_str());
     if (!file.is_open()) { 
          // handle error.
     }
     // write contents...
}
```