# Does C++11 offer a better way to concatenate strings on the fly?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, concatenation, string-formatting

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/900035/207655) answer, and I wonder (I hope) if C++11 has come up with a native better method to concatenate, and possibly format, strings.

With "better" I mean actually *really* one-line, like in pretty much all higher level languages (bonus points if it supports something like python's "formatted string"%(tuple) syntax but I guess that's really hoping for too much).

The ideal result should be something like:

```
my_func("bla bla bla" << int(my_int) << "bla bla bla");
```

The only barely acceptable methods listed in that answer are the fastformat ones, but I wonder if C++11 managed to do better.

Comment: concatenation or conversion?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

C++11 introduces `to_string()` functions:

```
my_func("bla bla bla" + to_string(my_int) + "bla bla bla");
```