# std::to_string - more than instance of overloaded function matches the argument list

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11

`counter` is an `int`

```
void SentryManager::add(std::string name,std::shared_ptr<Sentry>){
    name = name + std::to_string(counter);
}
```

What would be the best way to stop this error? When I was being lazy I just made the int `long long` (or something), but I'm sure there is a better way of solving this.

Error message:

```
sentrymanager.cpp(8): error C2668: 'std::to_string' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

I am using Visual C++ 2010 Express.

Comment: Could you include the actual error message, and what compiler & version you're using (not reproducible with GCC 4.5).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

In VC++ 2010 there are three overloads of `std::to_string` that take `long long`, `unsigned long long`, and `long double`, respectively – clearly `int` is none of these, and no one conversion is better than another ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69cf73c6af5a7294)), so the conversion cannot be done implicitly/unambiguously.

In terms of real C++11 support, this is a failing on the part of VC++ 2010's standard library implementation – the C++11 standard itself actually calls for *nine* overloads of `std::to_string` ([string.conversions]/7):

> ```
> string to_string(int val);
> string to_string(unsigned val);
> string to_string(long val);
> string to_string(unsigned long val);
> string to_string(long long val);
> string to_string(unsigned long long val);
> string to_string(float val);
> string to_string(double val);
> string to_string(long double val);
> ```

Had all of these overloads been present, you obviously wouldn't have this problem; however, VC++ 2010 wasn't based on the actual C++11 standard (which did not yet exist at the time of its release), but rather on [N3000](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n3000.pdf) (from *2009*), which does *not* call for these additional overloads. Consequently, it's harsh to blame VC++ *too* much here...

In any case, for only a handful of calls, there's nothing wrong with using a cast to resolve the ambiguity yourself:

```
void SentryManager::add(std::string& name, std::shared_ptr<Sentry>) {
    name += std::to_string(static_cast<long long>(counter));
}
```

Or, if there's heavy usage of `std::to_string` in your codebase, write a few wrappers and use those instead – this way, no call-site casting is needed:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
inline
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value && std::is_signed<T>::value, std::string>::type
to_string(T const val) {
    return std::to_string(static_cast<long long>(val));
}

template<typename T>
inline
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value && std::is_unsigned<T>::value, std::string>::type
to_string(T const val) {
    return std::to_string(static_cast<unsigned long long>(val));
}

template<typename T>
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, std::string>::type
to_string(T const val) {
    return std::to_string(static_cast<long double>(val));
}

// ...

void SentryManager::add(std::string& name, std::shared_ptr<Sentry>) {
    name += to_string(counter);
}
```

---

I can't check whether VC++ 2010 succeeds or fails with the above usage of SFINAE; if it fails, the following – using tag dispatch instead of SFINAE – should be compilable (if potentially less clear):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

namespace detail {
    template<typename T>                   // is_float         is_unsigned
    inline std::string to_string(T const val, std::false_type, std::false_type) {
        return std::to_string(static_cast<long long>(val));
    }

    template<typename T>                   // is_float         is_unsigned
    inline std::string to_string(T const val, std::false_type, std::true_type) {
        return std::to_string(static_cast<unsigned long long>(val));
    }

    template<typename T, typename _>       // is_float
    inline std::string to_string(T const val, std::true_type, _) {
        return std::to_string(static_cast<long double>(val));
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline std::string to_string(T const val) {
    return detail::to_string(val, std::is_floating_point<T>(), std::is_unsigned<T>());
}
```

Comment: All of the overloads are present in the Visual C++ 11 Beta.  It's not really a failing of the Standard Library implementation:  some of the overloads were added to C++11 _after_ Visual C++ 2010 was released.

Comment: Defect Report 1261 happened in 2009; I think it's reasonable to blame Microsoft a *little* for moving slowly, at least.

Comment: @Zack : VC++ 2010 was written against N3000, which only has the three overloads mentioned.

Comment: Picking a draft version of a standard to implement and not paying attention to bugfixes after that point is not what I would call best practice.  [The IE team does this too](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mozilla.dev.platform/TcY72dL4AB4/discussion) and it's infuriating.

Comment: @Zack : Well, no one ever accused MS of following best practices... ;-]

Comment: Yes, the  9 overloads was what I had found and thought was correct, which is why I had the problem. It does seem silly that VS would be written without taking later additions to the current standard.

Comment: FYI `g++` version 4.4.7 on CentOS-6 also has the same issue (and is also from a similar timeframe as the above mentioned MSVC compiler).

Answer (score 11):

You have tripped over [C++ DR 1261](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#1261), which reads in part

> The code "`int i; to_string(i);`" fails to compile, as '`int`' is ambiguous between '`long long`' and '`long long unsigned`'. It seems unreasonable to expect users to cast numbers up to a larger type just to use `to_string`.

The proposed resolution is to add more overloads.  [GCC has implemented this already](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2009-11/msg00030.html); I guess MSVC hasn't.

Comment: The resolution was incorporated into the final C++11 Standard.  The Visual C++ 11 Beta includes all of the overloads.