# std::wstring to_wstring( double value );

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, std, tostring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [std::to_string - more than instance of overloaded function matches the argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664699/stdto-string-more-than-instance-of-overloaded-function-matches-the-argument)

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    double randDouble = 1245.432;
    std::wstring stringDouble = std::to_wstring(randDouble);
}
```

When I compile this in Visual Studio 2010 I get this error

> Error 1   error C2668: 'std::to_wstring' : ambiguous call to overloaded
> function  6
>
> 1> error C2668:
> 'std::to_string' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
>
> 1> d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
> 10.0\vc\include\string(688): could be 'std::string std::to_string(long double)'
>
> 1> d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
> 10.0\vc\include\string(680): or       'std::string std::to_string(_ULonglong)'
>
> 1> d:\program files
> (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string(672): or
> 'std::string std::to_string(_Longlong)'

Can someone please explain to me why the compiler is confused and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it list the ambiguous overloads?

Comment: @Pubby Edited with what it says

Comment: See the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664699/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a bug in Visual C++ 2010.  It has been fixed in Visual C++ 2012.

Comment: Oh... <Shakes fist at MS>

Comment: To elaborate a bit on this, the particular bug was, that their standard library only provided `long long`, `unsigned long long` and `long double` overloads. So to circumvent it, you have to cast the argument to the largest type of its kind (in your case `long double`).