# More than one instance of overloaded function to_string matches the argument list

Tags: c++

I did exactly what was written here: [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

But I get an error at the std of std::to_string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{

std::string s = std::to_string(42);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you read the first comment under that answer? Specifically "`to_string` not a member of `std` fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975341/to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std-says-so-g "

Comment: @JonnyHenly That's not the error message he says he's getting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::to\_string - more than instance of overloaded function matches the argument list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664699/stdto-string-more-than-instance-of-overloaded-function-matches-the-argument)

Answer (score 2):

The error message you get can't be generated for a standard-conforming library implementation.

So, the best solution is to upgrade the compiler (presumably it's some years old Visual C++).

An alternative is to use an argument of type `long`, and hope that that's one of the existing overloads:

```
std::to_string( 42L )
```