# Qt c++ aggregate 'std::stringstream ss' has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Tags: c++, string, qt, stringstream

I have this function in my program that converts integers to strings:

```
    QString Stats_Manager::convertInt(int num)
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << num;
        return ss.str();
    }
```

But when ever i run this i get the error:

```
aggregate 'std::stringstream ss' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

Im not really sure what that means. But if you know how to fix it or need any more code please just comment. Thanks.

Comment: `#include <sstream>`

Comment: As an aside, QString has a static function for constructing a string from a number. It's [QString::number](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8-snapshot/qstring.html#number).

Comment: Notice!  it's #include<sstream>, NOT #inlude<ostream>

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You probably have a forward declaration of the class, but haven't included the header:

```
#include <sstream>

//...
QString Stats_Manager::convertInt(int num)
{
    std::stringstream ss;   // <-- also note namespace qualification
    ss << num;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Like it's written up there, you forget to type `#include <sstream>`

```
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

QString Stats_Manager::convertInt(int num)
{
   stringstream ss;
   ss << num;
   return ss.str();
}
```

You can also use some other ways to convert `int` to `string`, like

```
char numstr[21]; // enough to hold all numbers up to 64-bits
sprintf(numstr, "%d", age);
result = name + numstr;
```

check [this!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191757/c-concatenate-string-and-int)