# How to combine strings and ints to a single string (C++)

Tags: c++, string, pointers, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ concatenate string and int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191757/c-concatenate-string-and-int)

I am tryinging to make use many strings and ints to make a single string but I am getting the message: "error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers"

This is my code:

`transactions[0] = "New Account Made, Customer ID: " + ID + ", Customer Name : " + firstName + " " + secondName + endl + ", Account ID: " + setID + ", Account Name: " + setName;`

(note that ID and setID is an int)

Comment: Try using `'\n'` instead of `endl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a stringstream:

```
#include <sstream>

...
std::stringstream stm;
stm<<"New Account Made, Customer ID: "<<ID<<", Customer Name : "<<firstName<<" "<<secondName<<std::endl<<", Account ID: "<<setID<<", Account Name: "<<setName;
```

You can then access the resulting string with stm.str().

Answer (score 1):

You should use a string stream: write the string into it; then write the int. Finally, harvest the result through the `str()` method of the stream:

```
stringstream ss;
string hello("hello");
int world = 1234;
ss << hello << world << endl;
string res = ss.str();
cout << res << endl;
```

Here is a [link to a demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/pRPMGO).