# How to perform IN in sql query using pqxx in c++ for postgresql?

Tags: c++, postgresql, c++11, libpqxx

How to perform `IN` in sql query using `pqxx` in `c++` for `postgresql` ?
I have `vector<long>` of ids and I need to update every row in table students ( to set `faculty_id` to some new value).
I want to avoid loop, new value (`faculty`_id) I get when I insert faculty with `prepared` `INSERT` statement.
Is possible at all to pass so iterable structure or create `prepared` `IN` query using pqxx ?

```
void prepareChangeFaculty(connection_base &c){
    const std::string sql =
      "UPDATE students SET faculty_id=$2 WHERE id IN $1"; // here is a problem
    c.prepare("change_faculty", sql);
}
```

$1 I have like vector of id of rows which I need to update

Comment: Please supply some code.

Comment: @Alexandros I have added some code with problematic part

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like that ([How to concatenate a std::string and an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191757/c-concatenate-string-and-int)) in C++11

```
string a="";
for (int k=0;k<myVector.size();k++){
    a += string(myVector[k]);
    if (k<myVector.size()-1){
        a += ",";
    }
}

std::string sql = "UPDATE students SET faculty_id=$2 WHERE id IN (" + a + ")";
```

Comment: Q: "why not something like that"? A: "because SQL injection"! (_Yes_, I know there will only be integers in myVector; _at least, on this development iteration_...)

Comment: @Massa The OP does not say anywhere that this app is going to used by other users except him, so what SQL injection you are talking about, when it is his DB server and his app?

Comment: I don't do SQL-injections (if I can avoid them) by principle. As I said, I _know_ `myVectors` is an integer vector (difficult to inject poisonous data on those) _for now_. The guy who will inherit the code can change it to a `string` vector, or `boost::variant` record, and the next guy in line with the same code five years from now makes the code into a library and link it to a web service and there is no budget to do a proper code review and the product has to be lauched ASAP and **BAM!**....

Comment: Then lets write all code in a way that makes it impossible for stupid monkeys to BAM in all possible futures ... lol

Answer (score 0):

I understand the concerns of @Massa, however I could not find a different solution than the @Alexandros one.

So, a bit improvement to this solution can be the use of std::copy

```
std::stringstream params;

std::copy(
    myVector.begin(), myVector.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(params, ","));

std::string sql = "UPDATE students SET faculty_id=$2 WHERE id IN ('"
    + params.str() + "')";
```