# Why cout<<"Hello world" + 10; prints d in the output

Tags: string, c++17

```
int main(){
    string s = "";
    s += 1;// if I do s = s + 1 code doesn't compile
    cout<<"Hello world"+10<<endl;
    cout<<s<<endl;
}
```

Why it prints d and random character. I try to think it as string is a char* then if I do str + 10 then it points to the 10 pos. I am not sure I am correct or not.

Comment: And that is `d`, what do you think it should be? I'm not seeing the problem.

Comment: `"Hello world"` is a string literal and **decays** to `const char*`. Then you add `10` to that pointer. Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and you'll find plenty of related SO posts for this. For example, [Why can you add an integer to a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299156/why-can-you-add-an-integer-to-a-string-literal) or [C++ Adding String Literal to Char Literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705956/c-adding-string-literal-to-char-literal)

Comment: The random char is from `cout<<s<<endl;`. What do you think `s += 1;` is supposed to do?

Comment: `std::string` is not an array. It encapsulates one. It is rather unfortunate that `s += 1;` compiles :/

Comment: @john yes it does. I suppose thats what the question is all about

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I saw your comment, how does it compile?

Comment: @john Because `operator +=` can take a `char` and the constant `1` can be converted to a `char`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Of course, very unfortunate. you'll be telling me that `s += false;` compiles as well.

Comment: @john [It does indeed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/014f706ffa32bc24)

Comment: @john Should do, that conversion is legal too :(

Comment: what are you actually asking? The title is about `cout<<"Hello world"+10<<endl;` but in the question you say that you expect `d` to be pritned which is already what happens. I suppose the question is about `cout<<s<<endl;`, but thats not quite clear

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186107/my-code-works-now-but-why-adding-0-to-a-string

Comment: Another problem is that the text of the question keeps changing.

Comment: There was no reason to reopen the question. There are plenty of dupes for this.

Comment: @OP Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expcected output. But never rely on the ouptut of a program that has UB. The program may just crash. Also, refer to a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). **Don't try random stuff with c++**. It may lead to UB.