# How to concatenate a string and an integer

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

On compiling I am not able to concatenate the string.I am a little confused as to how do I concatenate.I tried to typecast and then concatenate,but that too throws an error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

string whatTime(int n)
{
    int h=n/3600;
    int m=n/60;
    int s=n%60;

    string s1=h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}

int main()
{
    string s=whatTime(63);
    cout<<s;
    return 0;   
}
```

I am getting the error

```
invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator+'
```

Comment: `":"` is not a `std::string`.  Adding `std::string` and `int` probably doesn't do what you want.

Comment: @Yakk but `""` is implicitly convertible to `std::string`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I don't see why that matters.  The error is long before the `=`.

Comment: Use `std::to_string` or use a `stringstream` to concat integers to strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ concatenate string and int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191757/c-concatenate-string-and-int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to create `std::string` from your `int` values

```
string s1 = std::to_string(h) + ":" + std::to_string(m) + ":" + std::to_string(s);
```

Remember you have to `return` from your function!

```
string whatTime(int n)
{
    int h = n / 3600;
    int m = n / 60;
    int s = n % 60;

    return to_string(h) + ":" + to_string(m) + ":" + to_string(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Me string not smart enuf to do dat. Must turn number to string before add to string. CoryKramer type faster. I show other way with stream.  Must include sstream.

```
stringstream stream;
stream << h << ":" << m << ":" << s;
return stream.str();
```