# string and int concatenation in C++

Tags: c++, string, int, concatenation, stdstring

```
string words[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    words[i] = "word" + i;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    cout<<words[i]<<endl;
}
```

I expected result as :

```
word1
.
.
word5
```

Bu it printed like this in console:

```
word
ord
rd
d
```

Can someone tell me the reason for this. I am sure in java it will print as expected.

Comment: C++ is not Java. What you're looking for is the `to_string` function.

Comment: [This answer has a C++11 solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/900035/1270789) as well as older solutions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++ is not Java.

In C++, `"word" + i` is pointer arithmetic, it's not string concatenation. Note that the type of [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) `"word"` is `const char[5]` (including the null character `'\0'`), then decay to `const char*` here. So for `"word" + 0` you'll get a pointer of type `const char*` pointing to the 1st char (i.e. `w`), for `"word" + 1` you'll get pointer pointing to the 2nd char (i.e. `o`), and so on.

You could use [`operator+`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) with `std::string`, and [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) (since C++11) here.

```
words[i] = "word" + std::to_string(i);
```

BTW: If you want `word1` ~ `word5`, you should use `std::to_string(i + 1)` instead of `std::to_string(i)`.

Comment: It is `to_string(i + 1)` not just `i`

Comment: @YuanWen Thanks for reminding.

Comment: When using Arduino simple cast to String can be used: `words[i] = "word" + (String)i;`

Answer (score 3):

```
 words[i] = "word" + to_string(i+1);
```

Please look at this [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) for more detail about `to_string()`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the following way:

```
  string words[5];
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
  {
      stringstream ss;
      ss << "word" << i+1;
      words[i] = ss.str();
  }
```

Comment: Why ? For efficiency or clarity or anything else?

Comment: I suppose, for efficiency. But in this example, when only one `+` to make each line, I think it is not so important.