# Ogre3d having unique node names error

Tags: c++, duplicates, nodes, ogre3d

I am working on city generation for a pcg game of mine. I have a for loop which makes 3 cities in random locations, I assign `parentIteration` to get that "id" for the city and do the same in the `for` loop where I make a building

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    parentIteration = i;
    std::srand(i);
    _rootNode = GameManager::getSingletonPtr()->getSceneManager()->getRootSceneNode();

    _cityNode = _rootNode->createChildSceneNode("cityNode " + parentIteration);
    generateCity(std::rand() % 10000 + 10, std::rand() % 10000 + 10, std::rand() % 11 +1);
}
```

building

```
for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfBuildings; i++)
    {
        childIteration = i;
        printf(" parent  %d and child %d \n", parentIteration, childIteration);
        Ogre::SceneNode* buildingNode  = _cityNode->createChildSceneNode("citybuildingNode"+childIteration+parentIteration );
}
```

However when I try to launch the game it will crash on creating the second city. Saying it already has a name similar to what it is trying to write. Yet my `printf` clearly show that the numbers at that point are all unique. Anyone know how to resolve this issue? (added picture for proof of output)

[image]

Comment: are you sure that `"citybuildingNode"+childIteration+parentIteration` does what you think it does?  Because I think you meant to do a string concatenation and not pointer arithmethic. `std::string("citybuildingNode")+childIteration+parentIteration` seems more appropriate

Comment: `cityNode = _rootNode->createChildSceneNode("cityNode " + parentIteration);`  -- I do not know `Ogre`, but that parameter you're passing -- what is the actual type that is expected?  You are adding a string literal and an `int`.  That isn't going to work as expected, unless there is some magic going on that I'm not aware of.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191757/how-to-concatenate-a-stdstring-and-an-int).  This is probably what your problem boils down to.  C++ does not work with string literals as does other languages.  You can't just concatenate a number onto a literal and get a string that is what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "itybuildingNode" in the error message suggests that

```
"citybuildingNode"+childIteration+parentIteration
```

is not working quite the way you wanted.

This is because of a couple things working against you:

1. "citybuildingNode" is a String Literal, and not a string object. It is litteraly just a bunch of characters in a row terminated by a null character and represented as a `const char *`, a pointer to that array of characters. It is low-level voodoo, the sort of stuff you might make a string class around. [For more information see String Literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)
2. Because it's not a string object, you can't pull any of the usual string object tricks like concatenating with a `+` and comparing with `==`. But because it is a pointer, the compiler interprets `+` as an attempt to perform pointer arithmetic and reference another location in the array. It compiles, but note how it turned "citybuildingNode" into "itybuildingNode". Oops.

What this looks like is something like:

```
const char* temp = "citybuildingNode"
_cityNode->createChildSceneNode(temp + childIteration + parentIteration);
```

which resolves to

```
const char* temp = "citybuildingNode"
_cityNode->createChildSceneNode(&temp[childIteration + parentIteration]);
```

3. Even if it was a string object, the C++ standard string object, `std::string` does not allow you to add numbers to strings. It only adds strings together to build a bigger string. To add a number to a `std::string`, you have to turn the number into a `std::string`. `std::to_string` can help you here, but there is a cleaner-looking way to do this with `std::stringstream`

Eg:

```
std::stringstream nodename("citybuildingNode"); 
// builds a string stream around the string literal
nodename << childIteration << parentIteration;
// writes the numbers into the stream the same way `cin << number;` would
// turning the number into a string for you
Ogre::SceneNode* buildingNode  = _cityNode->createChildSceneNode(nodename.str());
// gets the assembled string from the stringstream 
// null-terminated string like ogre expects
```

This gets you started in the right direction, but still allows for collision between child 1 and parent 10  ("citybuildingNode110") and child 11 and parent 0  (also "citybuildingNode110") and similar. So you really want something more like

```
nodename << childIteration << '_' << parentIteration;
```

to force a separator between the two numbers.

[Documentation for `std::stringstream`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

There is also another possible nasty. The `string` we just supplied to ogre will only exist for as long as `std::stringstream nodename` exists and it will die at the end of the loop that generates it. I do not see anything in a quick perusal of [the documentation](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/class_ogre_1_1_scene_node.html#aeaee9cb1cb0c23fab2cc9bab08f51181) that says ogre makes its own copy of this `string`. So play around a bit to make sure that you don't have to store this name somewhere to prevent it from falling out of scope, being destroyed, and leaving ogre with a [dangling reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer).

Comment: I would like to thanks you for the clear explanation on my mistake as well as why it was that I made the mistake and how to resolve it!