# Delete with PQexec by given ID in C++

Tags: c++, database, postgresql

I am taking ID from my user and then i want to delete that ID from the database. I am using postgresql. but the query is not running. When i give hard code value like id=5 then it runs but when i give it user's value like id = DeleteId then it doesn't run. Here is the function:

```
void DeleteValue(PGconn *conn, int DeleteId)
      {

       PGresult *res = PQexec(conn, "DELETE FROM testData where ID =  DeleteId" );

         if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK)
         {
           cout << "Delete testData record failed." << endl;
           PQclear(res);
           CloseConn(conn);
         } 
          cout << "\nDelete testData record - OK\n";
          PQclear(res);
      }
```

Comment: Doesn't look to me like you are passing `DeleteId` to your query. You need to concatenate your query string with id: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191757/how-to-concatenate-a-stdstring-and-an-int or use prepared statement.

Comment: I tried that also but that didn't work

Comment: Can you show your attempt with string concatenation?

Comment: Do you mean this?
DELETE FROM testData where ID =  DeleteId.c_str()

Comment: Also tried this one:

PGresult *res = PQexec(conn, "DELETE FROM testData where ID = " + DeleteId.c_str() );

Comment: `"DELETE FROM testData where ID = " + std::to_string(DeleteId)`

Comment: Its showing error on this too:


cannot convert ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘PGresult* PQexec(PGconn*, const char*)’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved my own problem.first concatenate it with the help of sprintf and then execute the query. Here is the solution of the problem

```
sprintf(sql,"DELETE FROM testData WHERE id = %d",DeleteId);
PGresult *res = PQexec(conn, sql );
```