# Append int to std::string

Tags: c++, stdstring

I tried two different ways to append an `int` to a `std::string`, and to my surprise, I got different results:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    s += 2;     // compiles correctly
    s = s + 2;  // compiler error

    return 0;
}
```

Why does it compile and work correctly when I use the `+=` operator, but fail when I use the `+` operator?

I don't think the question is like [How to concatenate a std::string and an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191757/how-to-concatenate-a-stdstring-and-an-int)

In that question,no answer uses `+=` operator.And the difference between `+=`
and `+` operator of `std::string` is the key to solve my doubt.

Frankly,the question is a good example for explaining why c++ is so difficult to master.

Comment: You are not adding a string representation of the integer `2` in either case. You want to use `std::to_string`.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the `operator+` is expecting a `string` not an `int`

Comment: You cannot append an `int` to a string. What you can do is append the **text** that represents an integer value to a string. Don't lose sight of that conversion step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate a std::string and an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191757/how-to-concatenate-a-stdstring-and-an-int)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**TL;DR** `operator+=` is a class member function in `class string`, while `operator+` is a template function.

The standard class `template<typename CharT> basic_string<CharT>` has overloaded function `basic_string& operator+=(CharT)`, and string is just `basic_string<char>`.

As values that fits in a lower type can be automatically cast into that type, in expression `s += 2`, the 2 is *not* treated as `int`, but `char` instead. It has *exactly* the same effect as `s += '\x02'`. A char with ASCII code 2 (STX) is appended, **not** the character '2' (with ASCII value 50, or 0x32).

However, string does not have an overloaded member function like `string operator+(int)`, `s + 2` is not a valid expression, thus throws an error during compilation. (More below)

You can use operator+ function in string in these ways:

```
s = s + char(2); // or (char)2
s = s + std::string(2);
s = s + std::to_string(2); // C++11 and above only
```

---

For people concerned about why 2 isn't automatically cast to `char` with `operator+`,

```
template <typename CharT>
  basic_string<CharT>
  operator+(const basic_string<CharT>& lhs, CharT rhs);
```

The above is the prototype<sup>[note]</sup> for the plus operator in `s + 2`, and because it's a template function, it is requiring an implementation of both `operator+<char>` and `operator+<int>`, which is conflicting. For details, see [Why isn't automatic downcasting applied to template functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45506372)

Meanwhile, the prototype of `operator+=` is:

```
template <typename CharT>
class basic_string{
    basic_string&
      operator+=(CharT _c);
};
```

You see, no template here (it's a class member function), so the compiler deduces that type CharT is `char` from class implementation, and `int(2)` is automatically cast into `char(2)`.

---

<sup>**Note:** Unnecessary code is stripped when copying from C++ standard include source. That includes typename 2 and 3 (Traits and Allocator) for template class "basic_string", and unnecessary underscores, in order to improve readability.</sup>

Comment: And why the 2 in the expression `s + 2` is not treatet as a `char` but in `s += 2`?

Comment: @AndreKampling: It's to do with the fact that += is a non-template function but + is a template function.

Answer (score 44):

`s += 2;` is not doing what you think it's doing. It calls the overloaded `+=` operator to a `char`. It does **not** append the *character* `'2'`, but rather the character with *value* 2, and the result will depend on the *encoding* used on your platform.

There is no operator overload defined to allow `s + 2` to compile<sup>1</sup>. Hence the error.

The solution in both cases is to use `std::to_string(2)` rather than the `int` literal 2.

---

<sup>1</sup> Essentially the reason is because `operator+=` is not a template function, but `std::operator+` is, and overload resolution will favour a non-template function over a template one.

Comment: What's about: `string operator+ (const string& lhs, char rhs);` as he uses `s + 2`? Why isn't the compiler using that `operator+`?

Comment: One of the other answers goes into more detail.

Comment: But I didn't see why the compiler call `string& operator+= (char c);` but not `string operator+ (const string& lhs, char rhs);`?

Comment: Methinks that's a (good) question in itself (it's to do with the fact that the compiler must try to convert 2 to a `std::string`, which it can't). Why not ask it?

Comment: @AndreKampling: I capitulated and added more detail.

Comment: 2 is of type int. It won't be implicitly converted to char because it would lose precision.

Comment: The fact that `s += 2` compiles really feels like a defect

Comment: See also this question that refers to this one about [Why isn't automatic downcasting applied to template functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45506372/why-isnt-automatic-downcasting-applied-to-template-functions).

Comment: @AndreKampling Lol... That question is asked by me :)

Comment: "overload resolution will favour a non-template function over a template one"  - that wouldn't explain why no function at all is found for `operator+`.

Answer (score 15):

The correct way to add to your `string` would be

```
std::string s;
s += std::to_string(2);
s = s + std::to_string(2);
```

Comment: Note that [std::to_string](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) is only available on C++11 and higher.

Comment: @AndreKampling It's 2017. Unless a question is specifically tagged or otherwise mentions C++03, it's fair to assume C++11 support is available.

Comment: The generally recommend way to output an object to a string, is to use an std::ostringstream, stream the object to that, and then use the .str() function to get the std::string from the std::ostringstream.

This should work for all C++ dialects, and all objects which have an insertion operator.

Comment: @CSM "generally recommended"? And why would that be? The function `std::to_string` is perfectly reasonable in this context, and was created for just this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

While @CoryKramer answer gives you the correct way to add an integer to a string, it doesn't explain why the instruction `s = s + 2` does not compile.

The difference between the two instruction is that in the first one you use the `std::string` 's [+= operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/)  while in the second instruction, the compiler tries to cast `2` to a string.

There is no implicit conversion between `int` and `std::string`. however, you can cast an `int` to `char`, so this is why `s += 2`works.

Comment: `s = s + 2` doesn't crash. It fails to compile.

Comment: `s + 2` does not compile, but `s + '\x02'` does. How do you explain?

Comment: @iBug I believe its related to '\x02' being a char, and the + operator knowing how to add a char to a string since a string is essentially a fancy array of chars.