# how adding string and numbers in cpp works using + operator?

Tags: c++, stdstring

I've used cpp for quite a while, I was known that we cannot add string and numbers(as + operator is not overloaded for that). But , I saw a code like this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string a = "";
    a += 97;
    cout << a;
}
```

this outputs 'a' and I also tried this.

```
string a ="";
a=a+97;
```

The second code gives a compilation error(as invalid args to + operator,  `std::string` and `int`).
I don't want to concatenate the string and number.
What is the difference? Why does one work but not the other?

I was expecting that `a+=97` is the same as `a=a+97` but it appears to be different.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191757/how-to-concatenate-a-stdstring-and-an-int

Comment: The first `string` is obviously not `std::string`.    You haven't provided enough information, so it is only possible to guess.  I suspect it is a `typedef` for some pointer type (e.g. `const char *`) so the `a += 97` does pointer arithmetic.      It may also be a macro that has similar effect (but other gotchas) to a `typedef`.

Comment: @Peter: "The first string is obviously not std::string" -- Huh? How do you arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: @Peter it can be `std::string` : https://godbolt.org/z/TnbsjcfE6

Comment: "I don't want to concatenate the string and number" what do you want instead?

Comment: the answer to your question taken literally is no. `+=` and `+` followed by `=` typically do the same, but not necessarily. Operators can be overloaded to do different things

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  I want to understand how its working

Comment: I know, and I suggest to rephrase it a little, because the quesiton you did ask is based on a false premise

Comment: @Peter  
`
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
 string a ="";
//   a+=97;
  a=a+97;
   cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
`
This is whole code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first snippet works because `std::string` [overrides `operator+=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) to append a character to a string. 97 is the ASCII code for `'a'`, so the result is `"a"`.

The second snippet does not work because there is no `+` operator defined that accepts a `std::string` and an `int`, and no conversion constructor to make a `std::string` out of an `int` or `char`. [There two overloads of the `+` operator that take a `char`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B), but the compiler cannot tell which one to use. The match is ambiguous, so an error is reported.

Comment: Shouldn't overload 3 of [`operator+`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator+) take a `char` as second argument? But I guess it doesn't work, because `97` is an `int` and no `char`?

Comment: @churill: Ah yes, you're correct. But the compiler cannot select that because it's not an unambiguous match. I'll update.

Comment: `a = a + char(97);` would be a workaround.

Comment: Hmm, but `std::string::operator+=()` is also overloaded for `char*`. So why no ambiguity there? I'm not sure I have this completely correct yet.

Comment: @FredLarson There's no `char*`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Overload 3 of `operator+=()` is `constexpr basic_string& operator+=( const CharT* s );`

Comment: @FredLarson Yes, I mean, there is no `char*` in OP:s code. Perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: My premise was that there was ambiguity whether to convert the `int` to a `char` or a `char*`, but both operators have overloads for both. So now I'm doubting myself.

Comment: @FredLarson `int` to `char*` won't happen implicitly.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: So I bet there's a different overload that's ambiguous in the `operator+()` case.

Comment: @FredLarson No, it's not ambiguity. It's that the template parameter doesn't match so it can't find _any_ overload (if I'm not confusing myself here :-)).

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I'm looking over the template vomit. I get mostly "mismatched types", but for two overloads I get "deduced conflicting types". Trying to understand the overloads in question.

Comment: @FredLarson :-) Yeah, I was looking at [`clang++`'s output](https://godbolt.org/z/d5od5TPrM)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Yes, clang shows the same thing as my g++. The conflict seems to be between the const reference overload and the rvalue reference overload. Fascinating.