# int to string in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the itoa function in Linux ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190229/where-is-the-itoa-function-in-linux)

I'm getting error in gcc while using this

```
     char pipeName [33];

     int pid= getpid(); 

     itoa(pid,pipeName,10);
```

I'm getting:

```
send.c:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `itoa'
```

I included `<stdlib.h>` and `<stdio.h>`. What's wrong here?