# FizzBuzz Disaster

Tags: c++, terminal, fizzbuzz

I wanted to test my C++ skills by hammering out a quick fizzbuzz application. The code for it is posted below. However, when I run this application, something crazy occurs. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool ismultiple3(int i) {
  int res = i%3;
  if (res == 0)
    return true;
  return false;
}

bool ismultiple5(int i) {
  int res = i%5;
  if (res == 0)
    return true;
  return false;
}

int main() {
  string output;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    output = i;
    if (ismultiple5(i) || ismultiple3(i)) {
      output = "";
      if (ismultiple3(i)) output.append("Fizz");
      if (ismultiple5(i)) output.append("Buzz");
    }
    cout << output;
  }
}
```

So when I run and compile it, my whole terminal gets messed up. It seems like the character encoding is somehow being altered. It still accepts commands normally, it just looks off. I ran an ls to demonstrate this.
[image: Compiled, ran, and ls]
[image: Remainder of ls command]

Edit: In case anyone runs across this, I ended up adding an else statement and doing `cout << i` in it, because my computer's g++ compiler lacked C++11 support. The functions were also shortened and combined into a single function that accepts 2 arguments, `i` and `n`.

Comment: The line `output = i` does not do what you think it does!

Comment: The function `to_string` should come in handy. Also your `ismultiple` functions are way longer than necessary.

Comment: I'm stealing this question title for my next band name.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Whenever I have a problem I tend to expand out my code to make it easier for me to think about logically.

Comment: Well just so you know, 1 is treated as a `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other commenters have said, `output = i` is the issue here. The value of `i` casts from an `int` to a `char`, leaving the `output` string with a sequence [ASCII characters](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/) when you run that loop. For example, `97 == 'a'`, `144 == 'É'`, and so on.

I would consider rewriting the logic in the main function to simply have three `cout << ...` calls inside an if-else block. Additionally, the `ismultipleN()` functions can be replaced with simply `(i % 3 == 0)` for brevity.

Comment: As I commented earlier, I expanded out my functions to make things clearer for myself. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
 output = i;
```

You should use one of the methods suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228005/alternative-to-itoa-for-converting-integer-to-string-c).

For example:

```
std::string to_string(int x) {
    std::stringstream out;
    out << x;
    return out.str();
}
```

Comment: I tried using to_string() but apparently my version of g++ doesn't have C++11 support. Yaaaay. Streams would require restructuring unless there's an uncomplicated way to flush streams (which is already too complicated for a fizzbuzz application).

Comment: @derekwolf, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13388063/5987. Otherwise you might need to enable C++11 with a command line switch.

Comment: @derekwolf: I've made a small edit to my post. You could easily take one of the examples in that post, and convert it into a function, such as I have. Then, instead of `output = i`, you should do `output = to_string(i)`.