# Print int from signal handler using write or async-safe functions

Tags: c, signals, async-safe

I want to print a number into log or to a terminal using `write` (or any async-safe function) inside a signal handler. I would prefer not to use buffered I/O.

Is there an easy and recommended way to do that ?

For example in place of `printf`, below I would prefer `write` (or any asyn safe function).

```
void signal_handler(int sig)
{
  pid_t pid;
  int stat;
  int old_errno = errno;

  while((pid = waitpid(-1, &stat, WNOHANG)) > 0)
    printf("child %d terminated\n", pid);

  errno = old_errno;
  return;
}
```

Printing strings is easy. In place of the `printf` above I can use (without printing `pid`):

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, "child terminated", 16);
```

Comment: If your program is even slightly non-trivial, it might be a lot simpler to set up an `signalfd` and slot that into your event loop. Then you can do anything you like in response to the signal.

Comment: `signalfd` is not portable; it's Linux-specific. However, there's been a portable version of the same thing for pretty much the entire history of unix: [the self-pipe trick](http://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you really insist on doing the printing from a signal handler, you basically have 2 options:

1. Block the signal except in a dedicated thread you create for handling the signal. This special thread can simply perform `for (;;) pause();` and since `pause` is async-signal-safe, the signal handler is allowed to use any functions it wants; it's not restricted to only async-signal-safe functions. On the other hand, it does have to access shared resources in a thread-safe way, since you're now dealing with threads.
2. Write your own code for converting integers to decimal strings. It's just a simple loop of using `%10` and `/10` to peel off the last digit and storing them to a short array.

However, I would highly recommend getting this operation out of the signal handler, using the [self-pipe trick](http://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html) or similar.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have started to dig self-pipe trick. That seems far better.

Comment: Only the second option works for signals like SIGSEGV, SIGILL, etc.  The self-pipe trick won't work in those cases either.

Answer (score 4):

**Implement your own async-signal-safe `snprintf("%d` and use `write`**

It is not as bad as I thought, [How to convert an int to string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c) has several implementations.

The POSIX program below counts to stdout the number of times it received SIGINT so far, which you can trigger with `Ctrl + C`.

You can exit the program with `Ctrl + \` (SIGQUIT).

main.c:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* Calculate the minimal buffer size for a given type.
 *
 * Here we overestimate and reserve 8 chars per byte.
 *
 * With this size we could even print a binary string.
 *
 * - +1 for NULL terminator
 * - +1 for '-' sign
 *
 * A tight limit for base 10 can be found at:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c/32871108#32871108
 *
 * TODO: get tight limits for all bases, possibly by looking into
 * glibc's atoi: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190229/where-is-the-itoa-function-in-linux/52127877#52127877
 */
#define ITOA_SAFE_STRLEN(type) sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT + 2

/* async-signal-safe implementation of integer to string conversion.
 *
 * Null terminates the output string.
 *
 * The input buffer size must be large enough to contain the output,
 * the caller must calculate it properly.
 *
 * @param[out] value  Input integer value to convert.
 * @param[out] result Buffer to output to.
 * @param[in]  base   Base to convert to.
 * @return     Pointer to the end of the written string.
 */
char *itoa_safe(intmax_t value, char *result, int base) {
    intmax_t tmp_value;
    char *ptr, *ptr2, tmp_char;
    if (base < 2 || base > 36) {
        return NULL;
    }

    ptr = result;
    do {
        tmp_value = value;
        value /= base;
        *ptr++ = "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA9876543210123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[35 + (tmp_value - value * base)];
    } while (value);
    if (tmp_value < 0)
        *ptr++ = '-';
    ptr2 = result;
    result = ptr;
    *ptr-- = '\0';
    while (ptr2 < ptr) {
        tmp_char = *ptr;
        *ptr--= *ptr2;
        *ptr2++ = tmp_char;
    }
    return result;
}

volatile sig_atomic_t global = 0;

void signal_handler(int sig) {
    char buf[ITOA_SAFE_STRLEN(sig_atomic_t)];
    enum { base = 10 };
    char *end;
    end = itoa_safe(global, buf, base);
    *end = '\n';
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, end - buf + 1);
    global += 1;
    signal(sig, signal_handler);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* Unit test itoa_safe. */
    {
        typedef struct {
            intmax_t n;
            int base;
            char out[1024];
        } InOut;
        char result[1024];
        size_t i;
        InOut io;
        InOut ios[] = {
            /* Base 10. */
            {0, 10, "0"},
            {1, 10, "1"},
            {9, 10, "9"},
            {10, 10, "10"},
            {100, 10, "100"},
            {-1, 10, "-1"},
            {-9, 10, "-9"},
            {-10, 10, "-10"},
            {-100, 10, "-100"},

            /* Base 2. */
            {0, 2, "0"},
            {1, 2, "1"},
            {10, 2, "1010"},
            {100, 2, "1100100"},
            {-1, 2, "-1"},
            {-100, 2, "-1100100"},

            /* Base 35. */
            {0, 35, "0"},
            {1, 35, "1"},
            {34, 35, "Y"},
            {35, 35, "10"},
            {100, 35, "2U"},
            {-1, 35, "-1"},
            {-34, 35, "-Y"},
            {-35, 35, "-10"},
            {-100, 35, "-2U"},
        };
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(ios)/sizeof(ios[0]); ++i) {
            io = ios[i];
            itoa_safe(io.n, result, io.base);
            if (strcmp(result, io.out)) {
                printf("%ju %d %s\n", io.n, io.base, io.out);
                assert(0);
            }
        }
    }

    /* Handle the signals. */
    if (argc > 1 && !strcmp(argv[1], "1")) {
        signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
        while(1);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -o main main.c
./main 1
```

After pressing Ctrl + C fifteen times, the terminal shows:

```
^C0
^C1
^C2
^C3
^C4
^C5
^C6
^C7
^C8
^C9
^C10
^C11
^C12
^C13
^C14
```

Here is a related program that creates a more complex format string: [How to avoid using printf in a signal handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler/52145149#52145149)

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04. [GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/3ce92f93fede767a3f5613b621678781c624c4b8/posix/signal_write_safe.c).

Comment: This program does not work as advertised.  Program returns without the ability to press control-c.

Comment: @Deanie thanks for feedback. I tested again on Ubuntu 18.04 and it worked again. Please provide your distro / GCC version.

Comment: `gcc version 8.2.1 20181127 (GCC)` and `Linux unknown 4.19.8-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Dec 8 13:49:11 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.  When I run it, the command prompt returns... promptly!

Comment: @Deanie thanks. And what is your distro? Ubuntu 18.04 here.

Comment: `4.19.8-arch1-1-ARCH` Which is Arch Linux 4.19.8

Answer (score 0):

You can use string handling functions (e.g. `strcat`) to build the string and then `write` it in one go to the desired file descriptor (e.g. `STDERR_FILENO` for standard error).

To convert integers (up to 64-bit wide, signed or unsigned) to strings I use the following functions (C99), which support minimal formatting flags and common number bases (8, 10 and 16).

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define STRIMAX_LEN 21 // = ceil(log10(INTMAX_MAX)) + 2
#define STRUMAX_LEN 25 // = ceil(log8(UINTMAX_MAX)) + 3

static int strimax(intmax_t x,
                   char buf[static STRIMAX_LEN],
                   const char mode[restrict static 1]) {
    /* safe absolute value */
    uintmax_t ux = (x == INTMAX_MIN) ? (uintmax_t)INTMAX_MAX + 1
                                     : (uintmax_t)imaxabs(x);

    /* parse mode */
    bool zero_pad = false;
    bool space_sign = false;
    bool force_sign = false;
    for(const char *c = mode; '\0' != *c; ++c)
        switch(*c) {
            case '0': zero_pad = true; break;
            case '+': force_sign = true; break;
            case ' ': space_sign = true; break;
            case 'd': break; // decimal (always)
        }

    int n = 0;
    char sign = (x < 0) ? '-' : (force_sign ? '+' : ' ');
    buf[STRIMAX_LEN - ++n] = '\0'; // NUL-terminate
    do { buf[STRIMAX_LEN - ++n] = '0' + ux % 10; } while(ux /= 10);
    if(zero_pad) while(n < STRIMAX_LEN - 1) buf[STRIMAX_LEN - ++n] = '0';
    if(x < 0 || force_sign || space_sign) buf[STRIMAX_LEN - ++n] = sign;

    return STRIMAX_LEN - n;
}

static int strumax(uintmax_t ux,
                   char buf[static STRUMAX_LEN],
                   const char mode[restrict static 1]) {
    static const char lbytes[] = "0123456789abcdefx";
    static const char ubytes[] = "0123456789ABCDEFX";

    /* parse mode */
    int base = 10; // default is decimal
    int izero = 4;
    bool zero_pad = false;
    bool alternate = false;
    const char *bytes = lbytes;
    for(const char *c = mode; '\0' != *c; ++c)
        switch(*c) {
            case '#': alternate = true; if(base == 8) izero = 1; break;
            case '0': zero_pad = true; break;
            case 'd': base = 10; izero = 4; break;
            case 'o': base = 8; izero = (alternate ? 1 : 2); break;
            case 'x': base = 16; izero = 8; break;
            case 'X': base = 16; izero = 8; bytes = ubytes; break;
        }

    int n = 0;
    buf[STRUMAX_LEN - ++n] = '\0'; // NUL-terminate
    do { buf[STRUMAX_LEN - ++n] = bytes[ux % base]; } while(ux /= base);
    if(zero_pad) while(n < STRUMAX_LEN - izero) buf[STRUMAX_LEN - ++n] = '0';
    if(alternate && base == 16) {
        buf[STRUMAX_LEN - ++n] = bytes[base];
        buf[STRUMAX_LEN - ++n] = '0';
    } else if(alternate && base == 8 && '0' != buf[STRUMAX_LEN - n])
        buf[STRUMAX_LEN - ++n] = '0';

    return STRUMAX_LEN - n;
}
```

They can be used like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void) {
    char buf[STRIMAX_LEN]; int buf_off;
    buf_off = strimax(12345,buf,"+");
    write(STDERR_FILENO,buf + buf_off,STRIMAX_LEN - buf_off);
}
```

that outputs:

```
+12345
```

Answer (score -1):

If you insist on using xprintf() inside a signal handler you can always roll your own version that does not rely on buffered I/O:

```
#include <stdarg.h> /* vsnprintf() */

void myprintf(FILE *fp, char *fmt, ...)
{
char buff[512];
int rc,fd;
va_list argh;
va_start (argh, fmt);

rc = vsnprintf(buff, sizeof buff, fmt, argh);
if (rc < 0  || rc >= sizeof buff) {
        rc = sprintf(buff, "Argh!: %d:\n", rc);
        }

if (!fp) fp = stderr;
fd = fileno(fp);
if (fd < 0) return;
if (rc > 0)  write(fd, buff, rc);
return;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `vsnprintf` is not required to be async-signal-safe either. You would think this would be just a theoretical issue that doesn't matter in real-world implementations, but glibc's implementation is definitely **not** async-signal-safe as it uses `malloc`.

Comment: Also, `fileno` is not async-signal-safe. It is required to obtain a lock on the file, and could mess up badly if the interrupted code was in the middle of locking/unlocking the file. Fortunately, your use of `fileno` is bogus and unnecessary. `stderr` is file descriptor number 2. If you prefer not to use "magic numbers", `STDERR_FILENO` is available.

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected then. Maybe then create your own (async safe...) snprintf() function. (last time I checked apache's implementation was 50KLOC ...) BTW: I knew about STDERR_FILENO; it was just cargo-cult, programming, I presume) Basically, there is only the self-pipe trick that remains.

Comment: BTW: could there pe a solution of shoving the entire va_arg *contents* into a pipe (upto PIPE_BUFF, obviously) ? Its would require a deep copy, and the "arguments" may or may not be valid anymore at the time of processing, I realise that.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to make that work, since C provides no way to "construct" a new `va_list` programmatically. The canonical way to "emulate" async-signal-safe `printf` on top of a non-safe one would be to create a dedicated thread in advance that's responsible for performing `printf` requests. The signal handler would pass a pointer to a control structure containing the `va_list` pointer over a self-pipe, and would wait on another self-pipe to synchronize completion of the operation.

Comment: And: as you said, the recieving end woud have to construct a va_arg struct.You mean, the "deep copy" is not possible (and: certainly not portable). It was a wild idea, anyway. (a "deep copy" would only involve a "minor inspection" of the format string, ignoring all the modifyers. But maybe still too heavy for use inside a signal handler) And (as you said) the "recieving end" would need to construct a va_args thingy.

Comment: Actually, walking the argument list based on the format string is possible, albeit delicate. What's not possible is making a new `va_list` based on it to pass to `vsnprintf` or `vfprintf` later, simply because there's no programmatic way to make a `va_list`.

Comment: @R.. according to this: http://www-it.desy.de/cgi-bin/man-cgi?vsnprintf+3 vsnprintf() et.al. *are* async-safe. (the code example is terrible, though) It is gets confusing, I'm going to check the source ...

Comment: Yup, I got the feeling that it was a BSDism. Still need to check what GNU libc does. I remember cases (DEC OSF before 5.1 IIRC), where vsnprintf() was present in the library, but not exposed via a public header file). Before "standardisation" the return value could also be -1 on error (instead of >= 2nd argument) I still have the C compiler notes at work, I'll see tomorrow if the async-safe semantics were included there.

Comment: In glibc, the printf core code can call `malloc`, so there's no way it could be async-signal-safe. There may be some code paths where you can rely on it not calling `malloc` (depending on which formats are used, etc.) but unless this is documented, it could very well change from version to version, so it would be unsafe to rely on it.