# Why i am getting continuous SIGSEGV in the below C code

Tags: c, linux, signals

I am trying to learn Signals. I know invalid memory access will cause segfault. So, I register a signal handler for SIGSEGV signal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>


void sighandler(int signum)
{
    printf("%s\n", __func__);
}

int main()
{
    int *a = NULL;
    signal(SIGSEGV, sighandler);
    *a = 5;
    return 0;
}
```

Running this code, I am continuously getting SIGSEGV Signals. I thought i should only get the signal once. Can you guys explain why I am getting signals continuously

Comment: Also see [Formatted I/O inside signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17138158/608639), [`signal-safety(7)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) and friends. You must use async-safe functions in signal handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signal handler is returning to instruction that triggered it namely `*a = 5` which is causing it to loop.

You have several problems including the use of `printf` inside a signal handler.

There are safe and not-safe ways of dealing with this

## NOTES

Using `signal(2)` is not recommended for signal handling in general.

Handling `SIGSEGV` is even more complicated because of the way the signal semantics work.  Quoting from the man page:

> The only portable use of signal() is to set a signal's disposition to SIG_DFL or SIG_IGN.  The semantics when using signal()
>   to establish a signal handler vary across
>   systems (and POSIX.1 explicitly permits this variation); do not use it for this purpose.
>
> POSIX.1  solved the portability mess by specifying sigaction(2), which provides explicit control of the semantics when a
>   signal handler is invoked; use that interface instead of signal().

So the first thing you should do is use `sigaction`.

Next, handling SIGSEGV is a weird beast:

[How to write a signal handler to catch SIGSEGV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663456/how-to-write-a-signal-handler-to-catch-sigsegv)

and

[Does linux allow any system call to be made from signal handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675040/does-linux-allow-any-system-call-to-be-made-from-signal-handlers)

have good answers and get into specific details.  There are external links in some of the answers given there.

## How to do this using signal(2)

Well :-) let's say you *want* to use signal(2) and you *want to play with this in a weird way*....

You can use `sigjmpset` and `siglongjmp`.

`sigjmpset` marks a point where `siglongjmp` should jump to.  The first time `sigjmpset` is called (to set the point) it returns 0. When `siglongjmp` jumps to it, (which means it gets called again as a result of the long jump), it returns 1.

Which means we can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

sigjmp_buf env;
int sigsav;

void sighandler(int signum)
{

    const char msg[] = "Skipping signal\n";
    write(2, msg, sizeof(msg));
    siglongjmp(env, sigsav);
}

int main()
{
    int *a = NULL;

    signal(SIGSEGV, sighandler);
    if(!sigsetjmp(env, sigsav)) {
        printf("setting value of a\n");
    *a = 5;
    }
    else {
    printf("returned to sigsetjmp, but now we skip it!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

After the SEGV handler finishes, the instruction that triggered re-executes. Since you didn't do anything to prevent the next execution from faulting, you get SEGV again, ad infinitum.

See more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2663575/10678955).

Comment: While your point is correct,  this is more of a comment than an answer :-)