Clear I/O in Fortran or C
Consider the following Fortran code
  PROGRAM TEST
  EXTERNAL TARGET
  CALL SIGNAL (2,TARGET)
  OPEN (1,FILE='/dev/null')
  WRITE (6,*) 'first step'
  DO I=1,100000
  DO J=1,10000
    K=I*J
    ENDDO
    ENDDO
  WRITE (6,*) 'second step'
  WRITE (1,'(A)') ((' ',I=1,10000),J=1,10000)
  WRITE (6,*) 'third step'
  STOP
  END 
  SUBROUTINE TARGET
  WRITE (6,*) 'target reached'
  STOP
  END 

If I press ^C during the first step, the code works.
If I press ^C during the second step, the code aborts because the I/O system cannot be called recursively.
I would like an instruction like CALL CLEAR_ALL_IO to be inserted in the SUBROUTINE target ...
I have developed a partial fix in which the subroutine sets a COMMON variable that is examined in the loops that may take a lot of time ... but sometimes this occurs in other loops and fixing all the loops of a large program is fairly tedious. thanks.
I hope to write this answer to Ian Bush in the correct place. I have clic on edit (I have understood to do this) and I am here rather than in a section below where I expected to be ...
Dear Ian, thanks to your suggestion to specify the compiler, I have discovered that the error occurs with g77 - gcc version 3.4.6 (Ubuntu 3.4.6-6ubuntu5) - but is solved in gfortran  - gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) - at least for what regards this example. The previous gfortran version on my LINUX, however, gave this problem.
The sample input writes on /dev/null because the error occurred on all input units (even writing on internal files) and this choice does not disturb the host/terminal of who is so kind to test it.
I will tell you if the problem is solved also on real signal handlers, that return the control where is really needed.
thanks

Why don't you just write to another unit in the subroutine?  Like stderr.

You are ware of the issues associated with I/O in a Signal handler? I'm no expert here but see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138158/formatted-i-o-inside-signal-handler

Given signal handling this isn't defined in the Fortran standard it would help if you tell us what compiler(s) and operating system(s) you are targetting.

What you are doing is not really supposed to be supported by anything. You are completely on your own. If it doesn't work, it is not a bug or an actual real problem, it is just something that is not supposed to work.

GFortran I/O is very much NOT async-signal-safe, which is what would be needed for GFortran I/O to be guaranteed to work in a signal handler. If it appears to work in your example, it's entirely by accident.

Thanks very much @janneb I wanted to thank all but system does not allow
