# XCode graceful program shutdown

Tags: c++, c, xcode

I'm working on a server-like program in xcode, and I want it to shut down gracefully between debug runs. Basically the following line is not working

```
std::signal(SIGKILL, [](int){
    printf("got sigkill here!\n"); 
    //shut-down code here
});
```

I've tried trapping other signals, but so far SIGINT, SIGTERM and SIGABRT have not worked. How is xcode terminating the program, if it prints

> Program ended with exit code: 9

to the console?

**EDIT**
Apparently SIGKILL can not be caught, see [this wikipedia entry.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGKILL)

> In contrast to SIGTERM and SIGINT, this signal cannot be caught or
>   ignored, and the receiving process cannot perform any clean-up upon
>   receiving this signal

Comment: What do you mean by *is not working*?

Comment: I don't get "got sigkill here" printed to the console before I get "Program ended with exit code: 9". I do in terminal, which sends SIGINT on control+c, so I assumed I should be getting some output in the xcode console as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't catch `SIGKILL`. When a process receives `SIGKILL`, it immediately terminates. This is used to kill buggy processes that won't respond or ignore the regular `SIGINT`. If you could catch `SIGKILL`, and possibly ignore it, then there would be no way to kill a buggy process apart from rebooting the machine.

Also, note that you're calling `printf()` in a signal handler, which is not allowed. You can't expect this to work.

You can have a look at signal-safe functions in `signal` manpage: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html - `printf` is not part of it, so all bets are off.

From the manpage:

> A signal handler function must be very careful, since processing
>   elsewhere may be interrupted at some arbitrary point in the execution
>   of the program.  POSIX has the concept of "safe function".  If a
>   signal interrupts the execution of an unsafe function, and handler
>   calls an unsafe function, then the behavior of the program is
>   undefined.

See this question for safe alternatives: [Print int from signal handler using write or async-safe functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573000/print-int-from-signal-handler-using-write-or-async-safe-functions)

Comment: Hm, I see. Well, I've perused the manpage link, and it says that open/close are safe to call. Replacing my printf with close(open ("test", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT)); doesn't create the file if i press the stop button in xcode, although they are supposed to be safe to call. I'm guessing that maybe xcode is not signalling sigkill..

Comment: Apparently you can't catch sigkill. From wikipedia: "In contrast to SIGTERM and SIGINT, this signal cannot be caught or ignored, and the receiving process cannot perform any clean-up upon receiving this signal"

Comment: @Gleno Ha! Of course! I didn't remember about that. You can't catch `SIGKILL`; this is the signal sent to force process shutdown (in Linux, with `kill -9 <pid>`. I'll update my answer for future reference.