# "Abort trap: 6" error in C?

Tags: c, arrays, strcpy

I'm a beginner to C but I have this code running on xcode through gcc on terminal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
int main(){
    char name[12] = "Roman Mirov"; 
    printf("My name is %s\n", name);
    name[8] = 'k'; 
    printf("My name is %s\n", name);
    char greeting[] = "hello"; 
    printf("%s %s\n", greeting, name);
    strcpy(greeting, "greetings, "); 
    printf("%s%s\n", greeting, name);
    return 0;
}
```

And it outputs this:

```
My name is Roman Mirov
My name is Roman Mikov
hello Roman Mikov
Abort trap: 6
```

My question exactly is, why it generates error instead of showing the last line as output "greetings, Roman Mikov"?

Comment: There is no question here!!!

Comment: These two threads would serve you better in understanding The key point being mentioned about writing memory that you are not owning. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431147/abort-trap-6-error-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401116/abort-trap-6-in-c-program

Comment: @barakmanos I'll fix that if you can't see the question.

Comment: Yeah, I was eventually able to see it, but you should still make it clearer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case, the destination `greeting` does not have enough space to contain the whole contents of *source*, so it is an out of bounds access which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To elaborate, the size of array `greeting` is determined by the size of the supplied initializer,

```
char greeting[] = "hello";
```

in this case, `"hello"` which makes the size as 6, including the null-terminator.

Now, later you try to put a much bigger *string* into the memory,

```
strcpy(greeting, "greetings, ");
```

where, the source is of 12 bytes in size, whereas, the destination only contains 6. This causes the boundary overrun and the result, UB. The crash (or abort) is one of the possible side-effects of UB.

Comment: Is there a way to then change the value of a string (the whole array) if the new value is of greater size than the previous?

Comment: @Roman well, with arrays, it's not possible to resize. You may consider dynamic memory allocation, like `malloc()` and `realloc()`, is that's necessary.

Comment: @Roman For this simple program you can just specify a size for `greeting` which is large enough for all the greetings you may want to place into it. Otherwise, dynamic allocation is your friend, like Sourav said.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Now, what confuses me is how one tutor easily avoids my problem [here](https://youtu.be/7F-Q2oVBYKk?t=5m1s)

Comment: @Roman 1) UB is UB, there's no explaining it. 2) stop and discontinue watching that tutorial, N O W.

Answer (score 0):

In this line, you are allocating an array of 5+1 characters:

```
char greeting[] = "hello";
```

In this line, you are attempting to write 11+1 characters into that array:

```
strcpy(greeting, "greetings, ");
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case,`greeting` variable is array of `char` with size is 6 (Because `hello` and `\0` ).

So when you use `strcpy(greeting, "greetings, ");` to copy `"greetings, "` into `greeting` is cannot. Because `greeting` not enough to contain array with `11+1` character

=> Has error `abort trap : 6` here