# How To Avoid Abort Trap 6 Error at Runtime Using strncat()?

Tags: c

The **Abort trap 6** issue is stemming from calling the extra_info() method, where it uses strncat() multiple times. Removing this functionality would produce no errors at runtime.

From what I understood:

> Abort trap: 6 is caused by using
>   invalid indices pointing to non-existent memory locations
>   [Abort trap: 6 in C Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401116/abort-trap-6-in-c-program).
>   It may also occur when a variable memory needs to be freed. To avoid
>   this scenario, you can use multiple variables or free the single
>   variable every time it is be re-used. But I'm sensing the solution is much simpler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char line[1001]; // The line supports up to a 1000 characters
char lines[11][1001]; // An array of lines (up to 10 lines where each line is a 1000 characters max)
char info[100]; // Holds extra info provided by user

char * extra_info(
        char string_1[],
        char string_2[],
        char string_3[],
        char string_4[],
        char string_5[]
    );

int main(){

    int 
    i, // Line number
    j; // Length of the line
    char result[100], text[100];
    FILE *file;

    strcpy(text, "String No."); // The default text

    file = fopen("test.txt", "w+"); // Open the file for reading and writing

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){ // Loop to create a line.

        if(i != 9){ // If the line is NOT at the 10th string

            sprintf(result, "%s%d, ", text, i); // Format the text and store it in result

        }
        else{

            sprintf(result, "%s%d ", text, i); // Format the text and store it in result            

        }

        extra_info(
            "st",
            "nd",
            "rd",
            "th",
            "th"
        );

        strncat(line, info, 100); // Append the extra info at the end of each line        

        printf("%s", result); // Display the result variable to the screen

        strncat(line, result, 15); // Concatenate all strings in one line

    }

    strncat(line, "\n\n", 2); // Add a new-line character at the end of each line

    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){ // Now loop to change the line

        strcpy(lines[i], line); // Copy the line of text into each line of the array

        fputs(lines[i], file); // Put each line into the file        

    }

    fclose(file);  

}

char * extra_info( // Append user defined and predefined info at the end of a line
        char string_1[],
        char string_2[],
        char string_3[],
        char string_4[],
        char string_5[]
    ){
        char text[100]; // A variable to hold the text

        /* Append a default text into each strings 
        and concatenate them into one line */

        sprintf(text, " 1%s", string_1);
        strncat(line, text, 100);

        sprintf(text, ", 2%s", string_2);
        strncat(line, text, 100);

        sprintf(text, ", 3%s", string_3);
        strncat(line, text, 100);

        sprintf(text, ", 4%s", string_4);
        strncat(line, text, 100);

        sprintf(text, ", 5%s.", string_5);
        strncat(line, text, 100);

        strcpy(info, line); // Copies the line into the info global variable

        return line;

}
```

This code compiles nicely using GCC, but I've stumbled upon cases where the code works fine, nevertheless may ruin certain functionality because of this error. This has something to do with strncat() being called multiple times in this manner, which leads me into thinking there would be a memory allocation issue, but after trying other examples, the solution seems much simpler. Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about fixing the warnings first? You could compile like this: `gcc prog.c -Wall -Wextra`

Comment: Also, when you're having crashes then running in a debugger to locate when and where the crash happens might be a good idea.

Comment: @gsamaras There are no warnings compiling this with GCC without flags.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've located the issue before actually, therefore edited the post accordingly. Check out the 1st paragraph.

Comment: Nice one. Crashes when compiled normally, but does not crash when compiled with `gcc -fsanitize=undefined` :F

Comment: Compile with `-g`, run valgrind, crashes in `strcpy` - print the length of the string, it is 214 and you're copying 214 bytes to a buffer of length 100...

Comment: You can’t use `strncat(target, source, 100)` if `target` is 100 bytes long, even if it contains an empty string. You hit a buffer Overflow. The interface of the `strncat()` function is evil and vile and you should never use it. If you have enough information to use it safely, you can use `memmove()` instead.

Comment: indeed, it seems you've misread the documentation of `strncat`. Both `strncat` and `strncpy` have the `n` there that many people understand as meaning "safe" which they're not at all.

Comment: Any working code examples on this?

Comment: strcat() or strncat() produces the same error. Using a custom string concatenation method also does this. Even I were to malloc() them before doing this.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>*I wrote the accompanying code in March 2018 to satisfy myself about what goes on with `strncat()` for another question that got deleted before I submitted an answer.  This is just retargeting that code.*</sup>

The `strncat()` function is (as I said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54054423/how-to-avoid-abort-trap-6-error-at-runtime-using-strncat#comment94943480_54054423)) evil and vile.  It is inconsistent with the `strncpy()` interface, too — and different from anything you'll encounter anywhere else.  After reading this, you will decide (with luck) that you should never use `strncat()`.

## TL;DR — Never use `strncat()`

The C standard defines [`strncat()`](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.3.2) (and POSIX agrees — [`strncat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strncat.html))

> #### C11 §7.24.3.2 The `strncat` function
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
> char *strncat(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2, size_t n);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The `strncat` function appends not more than `n` characters (a null character and characters that follow it are not appended) from the array pointed to by `s2` to the end of the string pointed to by `s1`. The initial character of `s2` overwrites the null character at the end of `s1`. A terminating null character is always appended to the result.<sup>309)</sup> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `strncat` function returns the value of `s1`.
>
> <sup>309)</sup> Thus, the maximum number of characters that can end up in the array pointed to by `s1` is `strlen(s1)+n+1`.

The footnote identifies the biggest trap with `strncat()` — you can't safely use:

```
char *source = …;

char target[100] = "";

strncat(target, source, sizeof(target));
```

This is contrary to what occurs with most other functions that take an array size argument **<sup>1</sup>** in C code.

To safely use `strncat()`, you should know:

- `target`
- `sizeof(target)` — or, for dynamically allocated space, the allocated length
- `strlen(target)` — you must know the length of what is already in the target string
- `source`
- `strlen(source)` — if you are concerned about whether the source string was truncated; not needed if you don't care

With that information, you could use:

```
strncat(target, source, sizeof(target) - strlen(target) - 1);
```

However, doing that would be a little silly; if you know `strlen(target)`, you can avoid making `strncat()` find it out again by using:

```
strncat(target + strlen(target), source, sizeof(target) - strlen(target) - 1);
```

Note that `strncat()` guarantees null termination, unlike [`strncpy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strncpy.html).  That means that you could use:

```
size_t t_size = sizeof(target);
size_t t_length = strlen(target);
strncpy(target + t_length, source, t_size - t_length - 1);
target[t_size - 1] = '\0';
```

and you would be guaranteed the same result if the source string is too long to be appended to the target.

### Demo Code

Multiple programs that illustrate aspects of `strncat()`.  Note that on macOS, there is a macro definition of `strncat()` in `<string.h>` which invokes a different function — `__builtin___strncat_chk` — which validates the uses of `strncat()`.  For compactness of the command lines, I've dropped two warning compiler options that I normally use — `-Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes` — but that doesn't affect any of the compilations.

#### `strncat19.c`

This demonstrates one safe use of `strncat()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char spare1[16] = "abc";
    char buffer[16] = "";
    char spare2[16] = "xyz";
    strncat(buffer, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", sizeof(buffer) - 1);
    printf("%zu: [%s]\n", strlen(buffer), buffer);
    printf("spare1 [%s]\n", spare1);
    printf("spare2 [%s]\n", spare2);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles cleanly (with Apple's `clang` from XCode 10.1 (`Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)`) and GCC 8.2.0, even with stringent warnings set:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror strncat19.c -o strncat19
$ ./strncat19
15: [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO]
spare1 [abc]
spare2 [xyz]
$
```

#### `strncat29.c`

This is similar to `strncat19.c` but (a) allows you to specify a string to be copied on the command line, and (b) incorrectly uses `sizeof(buffer)` instead of `sizeof(buffer) - 1` for the length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *data = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    if (argc == 2)
        data = argv[1];
    char spare1[16] = "abc";
    char buffer[16] = "";
    char spare2[16] = "xyz";
    strncat(buffer, data, sizeof(buffer));
    printf("%zu: [%s]\n", strlen(buffer), buffer);
    printf("spare1 [%s]\n", spare1);
    printf("spare2 [%s]\n", spare2);
    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't compile with the stringent warning options:

```
$ clang -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror strncat29.c -o strncat29  
strncat29.c:12:27: error: the value of the size argument in 'strncat' is too large, might lead to a buffer
      overflow [-Werror,-Wstrncat-size]
    strncat(buffer, data, sizeof(buffer));
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
strncat29.c:12:27: note: change the argument to be the free space in the destination buffer minus the terminating null byte
    strncat(buffer, data, sizeof(buffer));
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                          sizeof(buffer) - strlen(buffer) - 1
1 error generated.
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror strncat29.c -o strncat29  
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:190,
                 from strncat29.c:2:
strncat29.c: In function ‘main’:
strncat29.c:12:5: error: ‘__builtin___strncat_chk’ specified bound 16 equals destination size [-Werror=stringop-overflow=]
     strncat(buffer, data, sizeof(buffer));
     ^~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

Even with no warnings requested, the warning is given by GCC, but because the `-Werror` option is absent, it produces an executable:

```
$ gcc -o strncat29 strncat29.c
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:190,
                 from strncat29.c:2:
strncat29.c: In function ‘main’:
strncat29.c:12:5: warning: ‘__builtin___strncat_chk’ specified bound 16 equals destination size [-Wstringop-overflow=]
     strncat(buffer, data, sizeof(buffer));
     ^~~~~~~
$ ./strncat29
Abort trap: 6
$ ./strncat29 ZYXWVUTSRQPONMK
15: [ZYXWVUTSRQPONMK]
spare1 [abc]
spare2 [xyz]
$ ./strncat29 ZYXWVUTSRQPONMKL
Abort trap: 6
$
```

That is the `__builtin__strncat_chk` function at work.

#### `strncat97.c`

This code also takes an optional string argument; it also pays attention to whether there is another argument on the command line, and if so, it invokes the `strncat()` function directly, rather than letting the macro check it first:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
** Demonstrating that strncat() should not be given sizeof(buffer) as
** the size, even if the string is empty to start with.  The use of
** (strncat) inhibits the macro expansion on macOS; the code behaves
** differently when the __strncat_chk function (on High Sierra or
** earlier - it's __builtin__strncat_chk on Mojave) is called instead.
** You get an abort 6 (but no other useful message) when the buffer
** length is too long.
*/

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *data = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    if (argc >= 2)
        data = argv[1];
    char spare1[16] = "abc";
    char buffer[16] = "";
    char spare2[16] = "xyz";
    size_t len = (argc == 2) ? sizeof(buffer) : sizeof(buffer) - 1;
    if (argc < 3)
        strncat(buffer, data, len);
    else
        (strncat)(buffer, data, len);
    printf("buffer %2zu: [%s]\n", strlen(buffer), buffer);
    printf("spare1 %2zu: [%s]\n", strlen(spare1), spare1);
    printf("spare2 %2zu: [%s]\n", strlen(spare2), spare2);
    return 0;
}
```

Now the compilers produce different results:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror strncat97.c -o strncat97  
strncat97.c: In function ‘main’:
strncat97.c:26:9: error: ‘strncat’ output truncated copying 15 bytes from a string of length 26 [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
         (strncat)(buffer, data, len);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$ clang -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror strncat97.c -o strncat97  
$
```

This demonstrates an advantage of using more than one compiler — different compilers detect different problems on occasion.  This code is messy trying to used different numbers of options to do multiple things.  It suffices to show:

```
$ ./strncat97
0x7ffee7506420: buffer 15: [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO]
0x7ffee7506430: spare1  3: [abc]
0x7ffee7506410: spare2  3: [xyz]
$ ./strncat97 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
Abort trap: 6
$ ./strncat97 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
0x7ffeea141410: buffer 15: [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO]
0x7ffeea141420: spare1  3: [abc]
0x7ffeea141400: spare2  3: [xyz]
$
```

#### `strncat37.c`

This is the all-singing, all-dancing version of the programs above, with option handling via `getopt()`.  It also uses my error reporting routines; the code for them is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

```
#include "stderr.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/*
** Demonstrating that strncat() should not be given sizeof(buffer) as
** the size, even if the string is empty to start with.  The use of
** (strncat) inhibits the macro expansion on macOS; the code behaves
** differently when the __strncat_chk function (on High Sierra or
** earlier - it's __builtin__strncat_chk on Mojave) is called instead.
** You get an abort 6 (but no other useful message) when the buffer
** length is too long.
*/

static const char optstr[] = "fhlmsV";
static const char usestr[] = "[-fhlmsV] [string]";
static const char hlpstr[] =
    "  -f  Function is called directly\n"
    "  -h  Print this help message and exit\n"
    "  -l  Long buffer length -- sizeof(buffer)\n"
    "  -m  Macro cover for the function is used (default)\n"
    "  -s  Short buffer length -- sizeof(buffer)-1 (default)\n"
    "  -V  Print version information and exit\n"
    ;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);

    int f_flag = 0;
    int l_flag = 0;
    int opt;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, optstr)) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'f':
            f_flag = 1;
            break;
        case 'h':
            err_help(usestr, hlpstr);
            /*NOTREACHED*/
        case 'l':
            l_flag = 1;
            break;
        case 'm':
            f_flag = 0;
            break;
        case 's':
            l_flag = 0;
            break;
        case 'V':
            err_version(err_getarg0(), &"@(#)$Revision$ ($Date$)"[4]);
            /*NOTREACHED*/
        default:
            err_usage(usestr);
            /*NOTREACHED*/
        }
    }

    if (optind < argc - 1)
        err_usage(usestr);

    const char *data = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    if (optind != argc)
        data = argv[optind];
    char spare1[16] = "abc";
    char buffer[16] = "";
    char spare2[16] = "xyz";
    size_t len = l_flag ? sizeof(buffer) : sizeof(buffer) - 1;

    printf("Specified length: %zu\n", len);
    printf("Copied string: [%s]\n", data);
    printf("Copied %s\n", f_flag ? "using strncat() function directly"
                                 : "using strncat() macro");

    if (f_flag)
        (strncat)(buffer, data, len);
    else
        strncat(buffer, data, len);

    printf("%p: buffer %2zu: [%s]\n", (void *)buffer, strlen(buffer), buffer);
    printf("%p: spare1 %2zu: [%s]\n", (void *)spare1, strlen(spare1), spare1);
    printf("%p: spare2 %2zu: [%s]\n", (void *)spare2, strlen(spare2), spare2);
    return 0;
}
```

As before, Clang and GCC have different views on the acceptability of the code (and `-Werror` means the warning from GCC is treated as an error):

```
$ clang -O3 -g -I./inc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror strncat37.c -o strncat37 -L./lib  -lsoq 
$ gcc -O3 -g -I./inc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror strncat37.c -o strncat37 -L./lib  -lsoq 
strncat37.c: In function ‘main’:
strncat37.c:80:9: error: ‘strncat’ output may be truncated copying between 15 and 16 bytes from a string of length 26 [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
         (strncat)(buffer, data, len);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

When run:

```
$ ./strncat37 -h
Usage: strncat37 [-fhlmsV] [string]
  -f  Function is called directly
  -h  Print this help message and exit
  -l  Long buffer length -- sizeof(buffer)
  -m  Macro cover for the function is used (default)
  -s  Short buffer length -- sizeof(buffer)-1 (default)
  -V  Print version information and exit

$ ./strncat37
Specified length: 15
Copied string: [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]
Copied using strncat() macro
0x7ffedff4e400: buffer 15: [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO]
0x7ffedff4e410: spare1  3: [abc]
0x7ffedff4e3f0: spare2  3: [xyz]
$ ./strncat37 -m -s
Specified length: 15
Copied string: [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]
Copied using strncat() macro
0x7ffeeaf043f0: buffer 15: [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO]
0x7ffeeaf04400: spare1  3: [abc]
0x7ffeeaf043e0: spare2  3: [xyz]
$ ./strncat37 -m -l
Specified length: 16
Copied string: [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]
Copied using strncat() macro
Abort trap: 6
$ ./strncat37 -f -s
Specified length: 15
Copied string: [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]
Copied using strncat() function directly
0x7ffeef0913f0: buffer 15: [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO]
0x7ffeef091400: spare1  3: [abc]
0x7ffeef0913e0: spare2  3: [xyz]
$ ./strncat37 -f -l
Specified length: 16
Copied string: [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]
Copied using strncat() function directly
0x7ffeed8d33f0: buffer 16: [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP]
0x7ffeed8d3400: spare1  0: []
0x7ffeed8d33e0: spare2  3: [xyz]
$
```

The default behaviour is also the correct behaviour; the program doesn't crash and doesn't produce unexpected side-effects.  When run using the macro and with too long a length specified (`-m -l`), the program crashes.  When run using the function and too long a length (`-f -l`), the program overwrites the first byte of array `spare1` with the null added after the end of `buffer`, and shows 16 bytes of data instead of 15.

---

**<sup>1</sup>** One exception is in `scanf()` when you use `%31s` or similar; the number specified is the number of non-null characters that can be stored in the string; it will add a null byte after reading 31 other characters.  So again, the maximum size that can be used safely is `sizeof(string) - 1`.

You can find the code for `strncatXX.c` in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub in the [src/so-5405-4423](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-5405-4423) sub-directory.

---

## Analysis of Code from Question

Taking the code from the question and changing `int main(){` to `int main(void){` because my default compilation options generate an error (it would be a warning if I didn't use `-Werror`) for the non-prototype `main()`, and adding `return 0;` at the end of `main()`, what's left gives me these errors compiling with GCC 8.2.0 on a Mac running macOS 10.14.2 Mojave:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes so-5405-4423-v1.c -o so-5405-4423-v1 
In file included from /opt/gcc/v8.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0/8.2.0/include-fixed/stdio.h:425,
                 from so-5405-4423-v1.c:1:
so-5405-4423-v1.c: In function ‘main’:
so-5405-4423-v1.c:32:29: error: ‘%d’ directive writing between 1 and 2 bytes into a region of size between 1 and 100 [-Werror=format-overflow=]
             sprintf(result, "%s%d, ", text, i); // Format the text and store it in result
                             ^~~~~~~~
so-5405-4423-v1.c:32:29: note: directive argument in the range [0, 10]
so-5405-4423-v1.c:32:13: note: ‘__builtin___sprintf_chk’ output between 4 and 104 bytes into a destination of size 100
             sprintf(result, "%s%d, ", text, i); // Format the text and store it in result
             ^~~~~~~
so-5405-4423-v1.c:37:29: error: ‘ ’ directive writing 1 byte into a region of size between 0 and 99 [-Werror=format-overflow=]
             sprintf(result, "%s%d ", text, i); // Format the text and store it in result
                             ^~~~~~~
so-5405-4423-v1.c:37:13: note: ‘__builtin___sprintf_chk’ output between 3 and 102 bytes into a destination of size 100
             sprintf(result, "%s%d ", text, i); // Format the text and store it in result
             ^~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

The compiler notes that `text` is a string that can contain 0 to 99 characters, so it could in theory cause an overflow when concatenated with a number and the `", "` (or the `" "` for one iteration).  The fact that it is initialized to `"String No."` means that there isn't an overflow risk, but you can mitigate that by using a shorter length for `text` — say `20` instead of `100`.

I admit that this warning, which is relatively new in GCC, is not always as helpful as all that (and this is a case where the code is OK, but the warning still appears).  I usually *do* fix the problem, if only because it currently shows up with my default options and code doesn't compile with any warnings with `-Werror` and I'm not ready to do without that level of protection.  I don't use `clang`'s `-Weverything` option raw; it produces warnings which are definitely counter-productive (at least AFAIAC).  However, I countermand the 'everything' options that don't work for me.  If a `-Wall` or `-Wextra` option was too painful, for some reason, I'd countermand it, but cautiously.  I'd review the pain level, and aim to deal with whatever the symptom is.

You also have the loop:

```
for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){ // Now loop to change the line

    strcpy(lines[i], line); // Copy the line of text into each line of the array

    fputs(lines[i], file); // Put each line into the file        

}
```

Unfortunately, when this loop runs, `i` is equal to `10`, which is out of bounds of the array `lines`.  This can lead to a crash.  Presumably, the index should be `j` instead of `i`.

Here's an instrumented version of your code (`so-5405-4423-v2.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char line[1001];
char lines[11][1001];
char info[100];

char *extra_info(char string_1[], char string_2[], char string_3[],
                 char string_4[], char string_5[]);

int main(void)
{
    char result[100], text[20];
    const char filename[] = "test.txt";
    FILE *file;

    strcpy(text, "String No.");

    file = fopen(filename, "w+");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file '%s' for writing/update\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (i != 9)
            sprintf(result, "%s%d, ", text, i);
        else
            sprintf(result, "%s%d ", text, i);

        fprintf(stderr, "Iteration %d:\n", i);
        fprintf(stderr, "1 result (%4zu): [%s]\n", strlen(result), result);
        fprintf(stderr, "1 line   (%4zu): [%s]\n", strlen(line), line);
        extra_info("st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th");
        fprintf(stderr, "2 line   (%4zu): [%s]\n", strlen(line), line);
        fprintf(stderr, "1 info   (%4zu): [%s]\n", strlen(info), info);
        strncat(line, info, 100);
        fprintf(stderr, "3 line   (%4zu): [%s]\n", strlen(line), line);
        printf("%s", result);
        strncat(line, result, 15);
        fprintf(stderr, "3 line   (%4zu): [%s]\n", strlen(line), line);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "4 line   (%4zu): [%s]\n", strlen(line), line);
    strncat(line, "\n\n", 2);

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        strcpy(lines[j], line);
        fputs(lines[j], file);
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}

char *extra_info(char string_1[], char string_2[], char string_3[],
                 char string_4[], char string_5[])
{
    char text[100];

    sprintf(text, " 1%s", string_1);
    fprintf(stderr, "EI 1: add (%zu) [%s] to (%zu) [%s]\n", strlen(string_1), string_1, strlen(line), line);
    strncat(line, text, 100);

    sprintf(text, ", 2%s", string_2);
    fprintf(stderr, "EI 2: add (%zu) [%s] to (%zu) [%s]\n", strlen(string_2), string_2, strlen(line), line);
    strncat(line, text, 100);

    sprintf(text, ", 3%s", string_3);
    fprintf(stderr, "EI 3: add (%zu) [%s] to (%zu) [%s]\n", strlen(string_3), string_3, strlen(line), line);
    strncat(line, text, 100);

    sprintf(text, ", 4%s", string_4);
    fprintf(stderr, "EI 4: add (%zu) [%s] to (%zu) [%s]\n", strlen(string_4), string_4, strlen(line), line);
    strncat(line, text, 100);

    sprintf(text, ", 5%s.", string_5);
    fprintf(stderr, "EI 5: add (%zu) [%s] to (%zu) [%s]\n", strlen(string_5), string_5, strlen(line), line);
    strncat(line, text, 100);

    fprintf(stderr, "EI 6: copy (%zu) [%s] to info\n", strlen(line), line);
    strcpy(info, line);

    return line;
}
```

When run, it produces output similar to:

```
Iteration 0:
1 result (  13): [String No.0, ]
1 line   (   0): []
EI 1: add (2) [st] to (0) []
EI 2: add (2) [nd] to (4) [ 1st]
EI 3: add (2) [rd] to (9) [ 1st, 2nd]
EI 4: add (2) [th] to (14) [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd]
EI 5: add (2) [th] to (19) [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th]
EI 6: copy (25) [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.] to info
2 line   (  25): [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.]
1 info   (  25): [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.]
3 line   (  50): [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.]
3 line   (  63): [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0, ]
Iteration 1:
1 result (  13): [String No.1, ]
1 line   (  63): [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0, ]
EI 1: add (2) [st] to (63) [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0, ]
EI 2: add (2) [nd] to (67) [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st]
EI 3: add (2) [rd] to (72) [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd]
EI 4: add (2) [th] to (77) [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd]
EI 5: add (2) [th] to (82) [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th]
EI 6: copy (88) [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.] to info
2 line   (  88): [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.]
1 info   (  88): [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.]
3 line   ( 176): [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.]
3 line   ( 189): [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.1, ]
Iteration 2:
1 result (  13): [String No.2, ]
1 line   ( 189): [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.1, ]
EI 1: add (2) [st] to (189) [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.1, ]
EI 2: add (2) [nd] to (193) [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.1,  1st]
EI 3: add (2) [rd] to (198) [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.1,  1st, 2nd]
EI 4: add (2) [th] to (203) [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.1,  1st, 2nd, 3rd]
EI 5: add (2) [th] to (208) [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.1,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th]
EI 6: copy (214) [ 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.0,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.String No.1,  1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.] to info
String No.0, String No.1, Abort trap: 6
```

When you observe that 214 bytes are copied from `line` (which is big enough to hold that string) to `info` (which is not — it is but 100 bytes long), the ensuing crash is not very surprising.  It isn't entirely clear what the desired behaviour is.

On my Mac, the `lldb` debugger reports the crash in `__strcpy_chk`; AFAICT, it's in the line highlighted at the end of `extra_info()`:

```
frame #6: 0x00007fff681bbe84 libsystem_c.dylib`__strcpy_chk + 83
frame #7: 0x00000001000017cc so-5405-4423-v2`extra_info(string_1=<unavailable>, string_2=<unavailable>, string_3="rd", string_4="th", string_5="th") at so-5405-4423-v2.c:86
```

So, while it apparently isn't `strncat()` that causes the crash here, the way that `strncat()` *is* used is not obviously correct — IMO, it is incorrect, but views may differ.  And I still stand by my basic conclusion: **Do not use `strncat()`**.

Comment: Well, thanks for all the bells and whistles. I'm assuming you meant sizeof(string) + 1 in these examples. I'll keep that in mind whenever I need to optimize this section. These are important notes for refactoring. Switching from strcat() is an easy fix, nevertheless wasn't the culprit.

Comment: I'm not sure where you think I might have meant `sizeof(string) + 1` and didn't use it — though if you're referring to the `fprintf()` statements in the debug-laden version of your code, then it's "programmer's choice"; I chose to report the string lengths, though it would be feasible to report buffer lengths instead.  It may be true that `strncat()` was not the culprit — but whatever protection it was imagined to provide was not actually provided.  And using `strncat()` correctly is hard enough that it is best not to use it — I stand by my **TL;DR** summary.

Comment: Your default compilation options are triggering all these warnings. Compiling with GCC alone would suffice for this snippet and if you throw in more flags there would eventually be more warnings. Things like no newline at end of file, etc, which wouldn't be critical

Comment: My experience suggests that compiling with these options ensures the code is more nearly bug free than not using. You may, of course, do as you wish. But if turning on the warnings shows problems that were not otherwise revealed, which is often the case, then it is sensible to use.  I will continue to use them for my own work; for some of my code, I use even more detailed warnings. I seldom accept code that generates any warnings, even at the office where the rules are much more lax.  I do so with gritted teeth, though. Strict prototypes are a very sore point there, but the code is ancient.

Comment: In theory you're right. But many well seasoned C libraries out there do have warnings when compiling without any flags whatsoever. In this age of agility, non-critical aspects of software are left to deal with later and even thrown to the back-burner.

Comment: It depends on which code you're dealing with. Where I'm involved in the writing, I expect the code I write to meet my stringent standards, and where people collaborate with me, they're expected to meet the standards unless there's a compelling reason why they can't be met. The situation when you're using someone else's efforts is very different. I don't use my default compilation options on other people's libraries if I'm building the library to use. I use their default options (again, unless there's a reason to change them). On SO, the code is under 'our' control; we can write carefully.

Comment: Compiler warnings are provided for a reason. Increasing warning levels allow the dedicated programmer to use the help of the compiler to discover where problems may lie in the code, even though the code would compile. There are some programmers that think nothing of using values that differ in signedness within conditional expressions, those that wish to avoid code failures don't. If your code doesn't compile without warning using `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, you need to fix your code.

Comment: Not adverse to this idea. But just because you can doesn't mean you should, and because you should doesn't mean everyone is happy. No working code with the sanest robustness is just as bad as doing nothing. Will not debate on best practices as of this writing, but would love to at some point in time.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was simple as I was sensing, nothing evil, vile or cynical in C at all. 1st of all strcpy() didn't have to happen, 2nd extra_info() was misplaced for its purpose, 3rd even if I were to use strcpy() the parameters are to be swapped. Hence the error **Abort trap 6**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char line[1001]; // The line supports up to a 1000 characters
char lines[11][1001]; // An array of lines (up to 10 lines where each line is a 1000 characters max)
char info[100]; // Holds extra info provided by user

char * extra_info(
        char string_1[],
        char string_2[],
        char string_3[],
        char string_4[],
        char string_5[]
    );

int main(){

    int 
    i, // Line number
    j; // Length of the line
    char result[100], text[100];
    FILE *file;

    strcpy(text, "String No."); // The default text

    file = fopen("test.txt", "w+"); // Open the file for reading and writing

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){ // Loop to create a line.

        if(i != 9){ // If the line is NOT at the 10th string

            sprintf(result, "%s%d, ", text, i); // Format the text and store it in result

        }
        else{

            sprintf(result, "%s%d ", text, i); // Format the text and store it in result            

        }

        strncat(line, info, 100); // Append the extra info at the end of each line        

        strncat(line, result, 15); // Concatenate all strings in one line

    }

    extra_info(
        "st",
        "nd",
        "rd",
        "th",
        "th"
    );    

    strncat(line, "\n\n", 2); // Add a new-line character at the end of each line

    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){ // Now loop to change the line

        strcpy(lines[i], line); // Copy the line of text into each line of the array

        fputs(lines[i], file); // Put each line into the file        

    }

    fclose(file);  

}

char * extra_info( // Append user defined and predefined info at the end of a line
        char string_1[],
        char string_2[],
        char string_3[],
        char string_4[],
        char string_5[]
    ){
        char text[100]; // A variable to hold the text

        /* Append a default text into each strings 
        and concatenate them into one line */

        sprintf(text, " 1%s", string_1);
        strncat(line, text, 100);

        sprintf(text, ", 2%s", string_2);
        strncat(line, text, 100);

        sprintf(text, ", 3%s", string_3);
        strncat(line, text, 100);

        sprintf(text, ", 4%s", string_4);
        strncat(line, text, 100);

        sprintf(text, ", 5%s.", string_5);
        strncat(line, text, 100);

        return line;

}
```

Comment: In the `for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)` loop, you are using index `i`, but `i` is set to `10` at the end of the previous loop, so you're accessing `lines[10]`, which is not part of the array, which is undefined behaviour.  If you'd used `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` in the first loop and `for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)` in the second, you'd have been told about this error by the compiler.  And, despite your assertion that there is nothing evil in the code, the mere fact that you are using `strncat()` leaves you open to errors because you are using it very aconventionally.