# How to write a formatted string to a file using signal safe functions?

Tags: c, linux, signals

Currently I am using some non-signal safe functions like `fprintf`, `snprintf` in my signal handler. But I need to replace it with signal safe functions like write. But the `write` function only use a buffer, or a non formatted string. Is there any other methods to print formatted string?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16891065/2630032

Comment: You could make your own (very) simpified "snprint" like function that does just what you need (probably just plain and simple `%s` and `%d`).

Comment: I am not allowed to use snprintf means, I cannot use its inner function like vsnprintf, etc... as well. So only allowed to the functions mentioned in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print int from signal handler using write or async-safe functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573000/print-int-from-signal-handler-using-write-or-async-safe-functions)

Answer (score 2):

Set a flag in the signal handler. Then do the writs to file after returning from the signal handler.

```
static volatile sig_atomic_t sig_rcvd = 0;

void sig_hanlder(int sig)
{
   sig_rcvd = 1;
}
```

If `sig_rcvd` is set then do write to file and possibly reset `sig_rcvd` back to 0. This way you are avoiding calling any async-signal-unsafe functions from a signal handler.

Comment: Nice idea. But unfortunately it's not useful in my case. In my signal handler what happens is only memory cleaning and killing all threads. So it won't return to main function again

Comment: If it's at program exit, then you don't have to kill the threads or cleanup memory (at least, on Linux). So, you don't need a signal handler.

Comment: But in between I need to print call stack  to a file

Comment: You can still come out of the signal handler (after setting a flag) and then do your callstack printing. For example: `while(true) { /* do things */;  if(sig_rcvd) call_func();}`  and then `call_func()` can print the callstack and then call exit().

Comment: @shaefeeq: just to see if I understand you right - your signal handler will kill all processes, and the code that has been interrupted by the signal will never resume?

Comment: Yes Stephan Lechner.. :)