# passing non-char* arguments to execvp

Tags: c++, unix, execvp

Basically, I want to exec a program called "worker" with 6 arguments that are ints...

```
char* args[7] = {(char*)"worker",workerID,i+1,msgID,shmID,semaphoreID,NULL};
if(execvp("worker",args)<0){
    cerr << "execvp failed" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

How do I properly cast these to type char* ?
I've tried prepending with `(char*)` and using stringstream to store them in char arrays, but I still get compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually convert them to strings.  Look at sprintf or at this SO question:

[Where is the itoa function in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190229/where-is-the-itoa-function-in-linux)

Comment: Ok, I've converted the ints to strings, but I still get this error 5 times...

`master.cpp:205:81: error: no viable conversion from 'string' (aka
      'basic_string<char>') to 'char *'`

once for each int argument

Comment: when I append `.c_str()` to the args, I now get this error...
`master.cpp:205:50: error: cannot initialize an array element of type 'char *'
      with an rvalue of type 'const char *'`

Comment: @AaronMampáro: This is really one case where you can use `const_cast`. The `exec` family of functions don't change the arguments that it receives, and the interface takes a non-const `char*` for some obscure reason (most probably to match the signature of `main`). Because the function does not change the pointed data, you can use `const_cast<>` to `char*` without any problem (well, also because the memory is really from a non-const object...). Alternatively, you can obtain the pointers with `&str[0]`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Thank you! The const_cast<char*> worked! Actually, thanks to all of you for building up to that solution haha