# C code int to string not working

Tags: c, string, int

Here is my code which uses itoa() function , seems not working. Let me make it clear, I am working on C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{       
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0;i<= 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
        {
            //printf("Hi\n");
            char fileName[10]="A";
            char append[2];

            itoa(i,append,10);
            strcat(fileName,append);    

            itoa(j,append,10);
            strcat(fileName,append);

            printf("i=%d j=%d\n", i,j);
            printf("%s\n", fileName);
            //FMS()             
        }
        //printf("Anuj=%d\n",i );
    }
}
```

### Output

RC4Attack.c:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `itoa'
RC4Attack.c:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to`itoa'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: `itoa`?? There is no `itoa` in standard library

Comment: "Let me make it clear, I am working on C" Then why did you tag C++?

Comment: [**Reference Page**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) *"This function is **not** defined in ANSI-C and is **not** part of C++, but is supported by some compilers."*

Comment: is one of the include is stdlib.h?

Comment: Which compiler/platform are you using? Do you have evidence that it has an `itoa` function?  How did you **link** your code?

Comment: But atoi() is working it means it should be supported. Isn't it?

Comment: GCC compiler. Yes I tried atoi() on it, it worked.

Comment: It isn't. There is an `exit` in `stdlib` but no `ixet`. Use `sprintf`, or, if you are feeling insecure, `snprintf`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190229/where-is-the-itoa-function-in-linux

Comment: Tip: Why not write directly into the result buffer? Double-buffering is only useful for graphics output...

Answer (score 1):

There's no itoa in standard C library. Instead, use sprintf.

```
sprintf(string_value, "%d", integer_value);
```

**EDIT**
Use `snprintf` to guard against buffer overflow as well.

```
snprintf(string_value, max_size, "%d", integer_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue two weeks ago,
I solved it by using sprtinf instead of itoa.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/

---

Did it look like this?

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{  
int i,j;
for(i = 0;i<= 4; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
    {
        //printf("Hi\n");
        char fileName[10]="A";
        char append[2];

        sprintf(filename,"%s%d",fileName,i);    
        sprintf(filename,"%s%d",fileName,j);    

        printf("i=%d j=%d\n", i,j);
        printf("%s\n", fileName);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I tried sprint, which changed my looping somehow infinite. Its below code:

#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
 
 int i,j;
 for(i = 0;i<= 4; i++)
 {
  for (j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
  {
   //printf("Hi\n");
   char fileName[10]="A";
   char append[1];
   
   sprintf(append, "%d", i);
   strcat(fileName,append);


   sprintf(append, "%d", j);
   strcat(fileName,append);
   
   printf("i=%d j=%d\n", i,j);
   printf("%s\n", fileName);
   //FMS()
   
  }
  //printf("Anuj=%d\n",i );
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

I can offer you 2 solutions:

1.) You could try to use a different c-compiler, some may work

2.) You could write this function easily yourself. Its only a small piece of code (see the following link)
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdlib.h/itoa

Also you could use a former thread about this topic which may help in your case:
[Where is the itoa function in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190229/where-is-the-itoa-function-in-linux)

Greetings
Marius