# Can't run to_string() function on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, linux-mint

I've got some code that I'm running on Mac OS X that can't be compiled on the Virtual Machine running Linux Mint. This is a simple example. When I run it in Mac, all is fine, but I'm getting issues when I run the same code on Linux, so I'm assuming the library I'm including is not there, but should I be getting an include error then?

Here's the example code that runs on Mac.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string> 
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std; 

int main(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                string test = to_string(i); 
                cout << test << endl;
        }
        cout << "done" << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

I get no issues here but running on Linux Mint, I get this when I try to compile:

```
for.cpp: In function 'int main()':
for.cpp:7:28 error: 'to_string' was not declared in this scope
    string test = to_string(i); 
                             ^
make: *** [for] Error 1
```

Am I missing something? Any help would be much appreciated!

**edit**

I realize I forgot to include `<string>` on here and I fixed it, but what I changed (`<string>` included) still doesn't compile on Linux. I've used `to_string` before. I know that much in C++. I also tried adding `<cstdlib>`. Once again, this DOES compile on Mac and DOES NOT compile on Linux.

Here is my OSX output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
done
```

Here is my output on Linux Mint (Once again, Virtual Box, g++ make):

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:9:28: error: ‘to_string’ was not declared in this scope
   string test = to_string(i); 
                            ^
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

You could reproduce the problem yourself if you don't believe me. It's the same code, you can see for yourself if you want.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string is in `<string>`. Should probably include that.

Comment: In C++ instead of this `#include <stdlib.h>` you should use: `#include <cstdlib> `.

Comment: @ Galik, Thanks for the reply. I tried that (tried using both libaries which worked fine on OSX) as well as replacing `<cstdlib>` instead of `<stdlib.h>`. For some reason, It still won't compile on my Linux VM.

Comment: Which version of gcc are you using? (As an aside, it's helpful to distinguish clearly between compiling and running - if it didn't compile on Linux, there was nothing to run, but in a couple of places you suggest it's a runtime error).

Comment: gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

Comment: did you install build-essential in linux mint?

Comment: Did you compile with `-std=c++11`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile your `for.cpp` file like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 for.cpp
```

and run it with:

```
./a.out
```

The support for the `to_string` function in the `<string>` header was added in the C++11 version of the language, so you need to tell GCC to use that version. You can use the `c++0x` flag too, for example:

```
g++ -std=c++0x for.cpp
```

And you don't have to worry about `<cstdlib>`, that has nothing to do with it...
`to_string()` is defined in `<string>` if you are compiling with C++11 (but is not defined, or unreliably defined as an extension feature, if you are compiling with an earlier version of C++).

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Comment: @ajaysinghnegi : I have a [`toString()` implementation](https://github.com/jpcre2/jpcre2/blob/release/src/jpcre2.hpp#L1284) in my jpcre2 library, also look [here](https://github.com/jpcre2/jpcre2/blob/release/src/jpcre2.hpp#L186). You may get some idea there.

Answer (score -3):

SOLUTION:

I found a better solution. For some reason, I've read `stdlib.h` will not work on some linux systems. I used a different function to convert `int` to `string`.

on linux:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

and then

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    char buffer[10]; 
    sprintf(buffer,"%d",i); 
    string stringInt = buffer; 
    cout << stringInt << endl;
    // do whatever you want with the string
}
```

**edit**

To the person that down voted my solution to this, here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190229/where-is-the-itoa-function-in-linux) from six years ago basically saying the same thing.

Comment: Maybe that solution from six years ago should also be down-voted?

Comment: You read completely wrong. `<stdlib.h>` works fine on linux, it just doesn't include the non-standard `itoa()` function.