# Which library do I have to download in order to get itoa() in C

Tags: c, itoa

I want to use `itoa()` in C . Which library do I have to download?

I would prefer to include a specific library instead of using my own code, but that may be wrong.

I have seen several examples of how to use `itoa()` but my problem is how to get the library file.

Comment: You should think about portability first, and how easy it is to mimic the `itoa()` functionality.

Comment: @haccks is `itoa()` standard?

Comment: @iharob; No. It is not an ANSI C standard function. Removing my comment

Comment: Take also a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190229/where-is-the-itoa-function-in-linux)

Comment: Which OS and compiler are you using?

Comment: As `itoa()` is not standard, code could "roll its own" when not available.  _Many_ source code versions exist.  Too many fail `itoa(INT_MIN, ...)`.  Rare platforms with non-2s complement give different results for `itoa(+0, ...) itoa(-0, ...)`.

Answer (score 4):

`itoa` is not part of ANSI-C. Nor is it part of any POSIX standard. On Linux + gcc, for instance, `itoa` is *not* present in `stdlib.h`. Including `stdlib.h`  (as suggested at one stage in the comments) on such platforms will not fix your problem:

```
 $ grep -w -R itoa /usr/include
 $
```

nope - it's not there!

Don't use `itoa`. Instead, use something portable, for instance `snprintf` or (if you are fine with gcc only) `asnprintf`.

If you insist on using `itoa`, then perhaps `#include <stdlib.h>` will help; if so the answer to your question would be that *on that platform* it's part of the standard C library, and not a library you need to download. If it doesn't work, then it's not part of the standard C library, and you should use a portable solution instead.

Also, be wary of `itoa` anyway. From a [random man page](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~devanbu/teaching/260/refman/ITOA.5.mm.html) on the internet:

> `itoa` does not allocate new memory space for the string, but rather returns a pointer to the internal buffer where the conversion takes place

`itoa` is not reentrant (therefore not thread safe), and solutions like the first one [here](http://www.jb.man.ac.uk/~slowe/cpp/itoa.html) cannot be either whilst maintaining the same API. A better solution is the second answer here: [Where is the itoa function in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190229/where-is-the-itoa-function-in-linux)