# How to write an int using fwrite()

Tags: c, file-io

Let's say I have a `int largeInt = 9999999` and `char buffer[100]`, how can I convert `largeInt` into a string (I tried `buffer = largeInt`, doesn't work) and then `fwrite()` to a file stream `myFile`?

Now what if I want to write "The large number is (value of `largeInt`)." to `myFile`?

Comment: Do you want `largeInt` to be written to the file in binary or as text?

Comment: You *do* know about [`fprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)?

Comment: Why do you want to use `fwrite`? Or does the function used not matter, you just want it as a string on the file? (`fwrite` is usually the wrong choice if you want to write text to a file.)

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg fprintf() decreases speed as it should format the text

Comment: @Ehsan: Don't worry about small performance differences until you know that you really need the speed, and that you have profiled your program to find where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: @Ehsan Which still needs to be done to "convert" the number to a string.

Comment: @FUZxxl I want to write it as text. @JoachimPileborg I do know about `fprintf()` I think it would be better in this scenario. but I want to see how `fwrite()` works just in case I need to use it. Also I wonder how to convert a `int` that's more than 1 digit to a string in C?

Comment: Have you looked at [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the non-standard `itoa()` function as described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) and convert the number to string and then format your sentence using `sscanf` to format it.

> **`itoa()` : Converts an integer value to a null-terminated string using the specified base and stores the result in the array given by str parameter.**

Then write the sentence to your file using `fwrite`.

Comment: Thank you so much. And from the documentation I noticed that `itoa()` has a return value, which is a pointer to the resulting null-terminated string, same as parameter string... I wonder why it is designed this way. I thought strings are arrays in C, and arrays don't need to be returned.

Comment: `itoa()` is definitely non-standard.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190229/where-is-the-itoa-function-in-linux

Answer (score 3):

An example :

```
int largeInt = 9999999;
FILE* f = fopen("wy.txt", "w");
fprintf(f, "%d", largeInt);
```

Please refer this link:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/

If you want use `fwrite`,

```
char str[100];
memset(str, '\0', 100);
int largeInt = 9999999;
sprintf(str,"%d",largeInt);

FILE* f = fopen("wy.txt", "wb");
fwrite(str, sizeof(char), strlen(str), f);
```