# Write() gives weird symbols for integer

Tags: c, linux

I need to print out a string along with a integer in a signal handler function. I was told that write is signal safe. So far I have tried to print out an integer with write but it gives off weird symbols. Write worked for a char array of characters but doesn't work for integers. Any advice would be much appreciated. Below is my code which gave off the error.

```
    #include<stdio.h> 
    #include<wait.h> 
    #include<signal.h> 
    #include<unistd.h>
    int main() 
    { 
        int x[] = {100000};
        write(1, x, sizeof(x));
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What are you expecting to get written?

Comment: If you don't understand the relationship between your array contents and the file, look at the file -- and your memory -- with a hex editor. Memory contents aren't encoded in ASCII (absent an effort to make it so), so you can't expect a textual representation when you dump them directly to disk.

Comment: I just write to print the integer to the console.

Comment: 100000 is 000186a0 in hex.  So the bytes are 00, 01, 86, a0.  If your machine is little-endian, then they will come out as a0, 86, 01, 00.  The first two characters are non-ascii.  What exactly are you expecting?  If you want to see a textual representation of your integer, then you first need to convert it to a printable string.

Comment: `write` prints raw bytes, and the raw bytes of 100000 aren't the same as the raw bytes of the string "100000". Even though write is async-signal-safe, it doesn't fit your other important requirement that you print an integer as a string.

Comment: Maybe convert the integer into an array of characters?

Comment: Just for reference, there's list of signal safe functions [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03).

Answer (score 1):

When I compile your program and redirect the output through `hexdump`, this is the output I get:

> ```
> $ gcc t.c
> $ ./a.out | hexdump
> 0000000 86a0 0001
> 0000004
> $
> ```

Then, we note that `100000` in hexadecimal is `0x186a0`. What your program does is emit the raw bytes for the object that represents the number `100000`.

If you want to print the number `100000` to the output in ASCII, you can write your own routine for doing so. For example:

```
void
print_number(unsigned x) {
    if (x >= 10) print_number(x/10);
    write(1, "0123456789" + (x%10), 1);
}
```

A better way would be to emit the converted characters into a buffer, and use a single `write` call on the buffer text that now holds the string version of the number.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29544416/315052

Answer (score 1):

Here are the bytes that make up the integer 100000 in memory, that I've converted to hexadecimal:

```
A0 86 01 00
```

Here are the bytes that `write(1, x, sizeof(x))` prints, in hexadecimal:

```
A0 86 01 00
```

Here are the bytes that `printf("%d", x[0])` prints, in hexadecimal:

```
31 30 30 30 30 30
```

31 (hexadecimal) is the ASCII code for the digit 1 and 30 is for the digit 0. But A0, 87, 01 and 00 are strange symbols. When you use `printf` it converts the number into something designed for humans to read; `write` does not such conversion.

To print numbers to the console in a way that can be understood by people, use `printf`. But you shouldn't use `printf` inside a signal handler, you say - that's correct, because you shouldn't *write to the console* inside a signal handler. (Would it be okay if your signal handler writes in the middle of a different write?)

If this is just a test, calling `printf` in the signal handler might be good enough, but every now-and-again it'll crash, so don't do that in programs that you give to other people.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. But I sorta have to use write() inside a signal handler and its not optional.This is just one part of my project. Is there any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Use a different function to convert the number into decimal digits first. Such as snprintf. But I'm not sure if snprintf can be used inside a signal handler either.