# I'm trying to make a function that prints a floating point numbers without using any standard library functions in C

Tags: c, floating-point

```
void    putfnbr(float number)
{
    int a = (int) number;
    putnbr(a);
    write(1, ".", 1);
    int i = 6;
    while (i > 0)
    {

        number = (number - a) * (10);
        a = (int) number;
        putnbr(a);
        i--;
    }
}
putfnbr(123.456555);// output 123.456558 
printf("\n%f", 123.456555); // output 123.456555
```

this function works well however the last number
it's converting to another number in this example:
5 becomes 8,
I want it to print the whole number as it's as the `printf()` dose

Comment: Note that `%f` in `printf` works with `double` arguments,not `float`. The `f` refers to fixed digit printing, not `float`.  Note that if you cast a floating-point operand to integer type, the behavior is undefined if the value is out or range of the integer type.

Comment: @Kaz A `float` passed as a _variadic_ parameter gets promoted to `double` by the caller. With: `float x = 123.456; void foo(float y) { ... } foo(x); printf("%f\n",x);` then `x` gets passed to `foo` as a `float` but as a `double` to `printf`. And, _The `f` refers to fixed digit printing, not `float`_? Do you mean `d`? For `%f`, this is `float/double` and _not_ "fixed" (i.e. integer)

Comment: See also [how to convert a float number to string to print it using write() function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69248148/2410359).

Comment: @HssainAitkadir Accurately converting a floating-point number to a properly-rounded string of decimal digits turns out to be a fantastically hard problem.  If you can come close, you should consider that a success.  Trying to get exactly the same result that `printf` does, in every case, is probably not achievable without a truly unreasonable amount of time and effort.

Comment: @CraigEstey `%f` prints in a fixed decimal format like 123.456, with a fixed number of places past the decimal, given by the precision. `printf` also supports `%e` (exponent notation) and `%g` (general: it chooses the representation).

Comment: @SteveSummit  I think it's a fantastically hard problem to try to do in portable C code, that is agnostic of the floating-point format. If you assume concretes like "IEEE 64 bit double with a 52 bit mantissa with an implicit leading 1, 11 bit binary exponent with such and such bias and one bit sign", that will tend to simplify things.

Comment: Works OK for many values.  Failed cases: Improper rounding, e.g.: `putfnbr(0.999999f)` prints `"0.999999"` rather than 7 digit `"0.9999999"` or  best 6-digit `"1.000000"`.  Fails for large value, NaN, -0.0.

Comment: @Kaz  I'd say a definitive answer to handle all `float` without library support is very challenging.  For a learners, this task encourages short cuts, UB and not full range correctness.

Comment: Thank you guys for your time and useful information I really appreciate

Comment: Hssain Aitkadir, `putfnbr(float number)` --> `putfnbr(double number)`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the closest `float` value to the number `123.456555` is actually 123.4565582275390625 (0x1.edd384p+6), so that is what you get when you print it.

The printf format `%f` prints a `double`, for which the closest value is 123.4565549999999944930095807649195194244384765625 (0x1.edd38327674d1p+6) so when you print rounded to 6 decimal places (the default with `%f`) you get what you see.

If you change your putfnbr routine to use a `double` instead of a `float`, you'll print the value 123.456554, because you are always rounding towards zero -- you really should be rounding the last digit to the nearest integer.  Unfortunately that turns out to be very hard to do while still getting all the corner cases right.

One other note -- your code will misbehave for negative numbers as written.

Comment: Yeah but printf print it like that 123.456555
doesn't changing the last number to 4

Comment: because printf rounds to nearest 6 decimal places (by default), while your code rounds towards 0.

Comment: The OP's request was to not use any standard library functions, and `round` is a standard library function (albeit one that often is inlined to a single instruction)

Comment: `if (i == 1) a = (int)(number + 0.5);`, about 5% of the time, will result in `a = 10` rather than 0 to 9  Code will need to propogate a carry.

Comment: True -- that doesn't really work.  Need to round to the appropriate precision before printing any digits.